# Requests for reopen and undelete votes for closed and deleted questions

Tags: support, big-list, undelete-request, re-open

Since I expect this may prove rather useful, I'm blatantly purloining Asaf's [question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6424/462) from meta.math.se.

> Please post general requests for reopen votes as answers below.
>
> Beware that "short" requests such as "request reopening of <*link*>" may be automatically converted to comments by the SE software, so you will need to say more, such as why you think that the question should be reopened.
>
> Please do not use this thread to engage in debates on contentious matters (e.g. reasons for closure). That should be done in a separate thread - which can be linked to from here.
>
> If a question is reopened then please put [REOPENED] at the start of the request (answer).

Of course, each requested question may need some editing or other improvements before it is fit, and as indicated [elsewhere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134562/set-theory-forcing#comment346706_134562), this is desirable, and I hope may be expedited through this thread.

(Improvements on the phrasing are welcome.)

Comment: Not entirely necessary. There's a reopen queue now. A closed post can be put into the reopen queue by editing or voting to reopen. 3k+ users can vote to reopen (or alternatively vote against it). If this mechanism fails, _then_ one can open a separate meta post about the question. I find that this is a more efficient process :)

Comment: @Manishearth: Not everyone has access to the queue history, so not everyone can tell when a thread has been "outlived its review" and it is time to come to meta. In the long run, I think it's better to have one post for "run of the mill reopen votes" rather than having more and more separated questions whose answers would consist mostly of "Done."

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah, I see your point -- but "outlived its review" can just mean "wait a day", regardless of its queue status. So, if a reopen vote or edit doesn't push it out of the queue in a day, then come to meta (and post on this post, or separately -- IMO separate meta posts lead to better discussion, but that's just me).  But if you take a look at the MSE post: Most of the recent ones are either obvious nos (closed post) user whinging about closed post, or obvious yes's (Awesome edit improved post).

Comment: These can be dealt with fairly within the review queue itself; giving an explicit platform on meta for people to whinge or where people feel obliged to post obvious reopens is imo unnecessary. Again, I don't know much about MO or MSE, so I could be grossly wrong here :). Just giving an outsider's viewpoint.

Comment: I agree with Manishearth: with the new "on-hold" -> edit -> add to re-open review queue mechanism, threads like this should be much less necessary.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Btw, [this](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/260/i-am-puzzled-by-the-close-votes) is why doing it separately is imo better, you get a lot more feedback and discussion.

Comment: I dont want to interfere here with anything but I disagree with Manishearth about the usefulness of this Request to Reopen List. At Math SE I have observed that it works very well and efficiently to get questions reopend without making much fuzz about it. At Physics SE, we controversely discuss each question that somebody thinks should get reopend at meta seperately at length with the effect that people just discuss instead of just doing it, and almost nothing gets reopend at the end.

Comment: Reopening questions the way people at Math SE do, has in my opinion the additional advantage that people who have less than 3000 rep and therefore not yeat access to the Reopen queue can take part in the reopen process by upvoting the answers of this post, which makes reopening of questions that deserve it more efficient.

Answer (score 19):

[[RE-OPENED and later CLOSED again]](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/220259/revisions)

The question [How the idea of adjoint matrix has been designed?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220259/how-the-idea-of-adjoint-matrix-has-been-designed) isn't great, but isn't awful, and [these](https://plus.google.com/+AllenKnutson/posts/LgLxgxsXNAT) [two](https://plus.google.com/+FrancoisDorais/posts/C6SBgvj5v8e) answers have been posted (and upvoted) on G+ rather than as answers, which is dumb. Let's reopen the question so that the answers can be added.

As an aside, the fact that Allen Knutson basically said "this is **going to be** closed, so I won't contribute my awesome answer here" says something terrible about how closing is treated by MO participants. The last MO board meeting included a discussion of how to address the problem of high-rep close-happy users making the site hostile towards grad students and advanced undergrads, who we *really want* to be comfortable posting questions and answers, but I don't think there was any publicly visible action on it :-/.

It also bums me out that Allen and François both have the ability to edit the question to improve it, but didn't, even though they were willing to put in the effort to post answers.

Comment: Why not move it to [math.se]? It seems like a better fit there. The user is completely new. Perhaps they'll even be better served by that site.

Comment: On the more general remarks, this would be an interesting discussion to be had. But perhaps this is not the place to enter it.

Comment: I think we should perhaps post a committed amplification on the aside here at meta, which has been much on my mind recently. (I might could get the ball rolling on that, but would need a few days at least.)

Comment: I know the more general remarks belong elsewhere, but I don't have the bandwidth to properly spearhead that discussion in the foreseeable future, so I let it leak out here. I guess math.SE would be fine, but I think it's just fine for MO too.

Comment: My impression is that the question asked is actually wanting an answer that is at an advanced undergraduate or beginning undergraduate level.  The answers of Knutson and Dorais (which I will review again) impress me as answering at a higher and more conceptual level which would be lost on the questioner and many readers.  I don't mind the question being on MathOverflow (and I won't dispute the awesomeness of Allen's answer), but I think more is needed from the question, specifically what level of answer would be appreciated.  Gerhard "Feels Professors Talking Over My Head" Paseman, 2015.10.07

Comment: I gave the final vote to reopen.  I don't have strong feelings on the question but I will defer to Anton whose vision gave us this site on its appropriateness.

Comment: It was later [closed again](http://mathoverflow.net/posts/220259/revisions). Perhaps it would make more sense to answer this [on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366845/is-there-a-way-to-think-of-the-adjugate-matrix-invariantly)?

Answer (score 10):

[REOPENED]

Why was [User retention rates on MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/790/user-retention-rates-on-mathoverflow) closed (on meta)? It's not a great question, I agree, but it's not exactly off-topic on meta to ask about user retention rates on the main site, and explanations for observed statistics.

Comment: I was not involved in the closing but I witnessed it.  I suspect it was the passive nature of the original question, asking other people to do all the work, when the question-asker could have done the work himself.  In the end, that's what happened.  I think people would have been happier if the question was asked in more of a can-do tone.  But presumably the question-asker did not know it's as easy as it is to do this kind of analysis.

Answer (score 9):

[RE-OPENED]

I believe the post [Can you write $\mathbb R^2$ as a disjoint union of two totally disconnected sets?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198428/can-you-write-r2-as-a-disjoint-union-of-two-totally-disconnected-sets) has been closed (or put "on hold") erroneously, as a duplicate of [Can you explicitly write $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a disjoint union of two totally path disconnected sets?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156/can-you-explicitly-write-r2-as-a-disjoint-union-of-two-totally-path-disconnecte)

Certainly the question is different; note that the consensus to the first question is that the answer is 'no', and the answer to the second is 'yes'. In some sense the closed question was answered by Gerald Edgar at the other thread, but I think that answer needs to be revisited as being not quite a complete answer, since  Włodzimierz Holsztyński has given what seems to be a valid objection in a comment below that answer, and no response to that objection was given.

Rather than have Włodzimierz respond at the path-disconnected thread (giving yet another answer to what is after all a different question), it seems to me proper to reopen the closed thread and have him and/or others answer. The question seems to me to be legitimately of MO level, even though it might be "trivial" for an expert like Włodzimierz.

Answer (score 7):

[REOPENED]

The question [A normal distribution inequality](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135593/a-normal-distribution-inequality#comment349395_135593) was originally phrased in a way that sounded like an exercise, and rapidly got downvoted and closed. I'm not a probabilist, bun in its current form it looks like it could be a genuine question worth re-opening.

Answer (score 7):

[REOPENED]

I find nothing wrong with [Linear Algebra Text Book](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141818/linear-algebra-text-book). Certainly MO.1 entertained plenty of questions about pedagogy without any controversy, and the selection of a linear algebra book with a view toward proof and standards of rigor is a perennial issue for teachers of undergraduate mathematics.

Comment: But perhaps it should be community wiki?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Yes, good point!

Answer (score 7):

[REOPENED]

Derek Holt, a highly respected researcher in group theory, wonders aloud why [A subgroup intersects conjugacy class of every prime power order element](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150380/a-subgroup-intersects-conjugacy-class-of-every-prime-power-order-element) was closed. I don't understand the closure or downvotes myself.

Comment: Perhaps it was closed because no context or motivation was provided. But since it turns out that the answer is a consequence of a difficult and interesting result (which I didn't know myself), this doesn't seem a valid reason for closing it.

Answer (score 6):

[RE-OPENED]

I think that the question [**How does a mathematician choose on which problem to work?**](https://mathoverflow.net/q/220643) was too broad in its original formulation (beginning: "How does mathematical research work?") and so I have revised it in a way that I hope allows it, as a soft-question, to be (re)re-opened. It is certainly not intended as a finalized product; only a more focused question than the original version.

I also re-paste here the edit summary that I left (specifically for its final sentence):

> I have substantially edited this question in response to its being re-closed: I removed some of the more general questions from the body, and tried to focus on the title question. If anyone feels that the change is too great, or otherwise inappropriate, I only ask that you revert the edit.

(If the edit is reverted, then [at least] I will not expend more energy on re-formulating the post.)

Answer (score 6):

[UNDELETED]

This is an undelete request for an answer on meta: namely, quid's answer to my question [Some proposals for modifications of the process of closing/reopening questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2806/some-proposals-for-modifications-of-the-process-of-closing-reopening-questions) .  The answer was accepted, but yet got deleted when quid left the site.   This was not quid's intent, and I also checked that quid was fine with the answer being undeleted (see http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37812/discussion-on-answer-by-sergei-akbarov-mathoverflow-user-jailed).

Comment: This is a reasonable request, and I think there should be one of these on meta to indicate the possibility of this type of undeletion.  I think it is better for the site if future requests of this nature are made directly to the moderators@mathoverflow.net, and not on a public forum.  (I am willing to expand on this through email if asked.) Gerhard "Seems More Respectful To Me" Paseman, 2016.04.16.

Comment: It seems pretty straightforward to me, and I don't see what is sensitive about the request that cannot be discussed publicly.

Answer (score 6):

[REOPENED]

The question [Has Perelman's proof been accepted or are there still unresolved issues?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/407914)  has been closed as of this writing. At first glance, this question seems to be of the genre, "Is this paper about a famous problem correct?" which the MO community has long ago decided is off-topic unless specific technical issues are spelled out in the MO question.  However, this question is slightly different. It is not directly asking about Perelman's paper; it is asking about *a statement published by Shing-Tung Yau*, raising doubts about whether Perelman's argument has been fully checked.

Complicating the matter is that Yau's comments are, by his own admission, phrased in a controversial ("subjective and argumentative"?) manner.  That initially influenced me to agree with those who voted to close (although I myself did not vote to close).  However, the *MO question itself* does not strike me as subjective and argumentative.  The MO question seems more in line with questions such as [Extent of “unscientific”, and of wrong, papers in research mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/q/351640), which asks about whether published and "generally accepted" papers are really as rock-solid as the mathematics community would like to believe.  In a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407914/has-perelmans-proof-been-accepted-or-are-there-still-unresolved-issues?noredirect=1#comment1048168_407914), arsmath wrote:

> I'm not trying to defend Yau, since the consensus is that he's wrong. I am trying to defend the principle that asking the question is legitimate. I don't see any way to interpret what happened here other than we as a community have decided to cover up any embarrassing fights. Which, to my mind, is more embarrassing than the fight itself.

I think that arsmath has a valid point.  Note that an earlier [comment by GH from MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407914/has-perelmans-proof-been-accepted-or-are-there-still-unresolved-issues?noredirect=1#comment1046106_407914), affirming the legitimacy of the MO question, has been upvoted 10 times as of this writing.  Even before arsmath's comment, I had cast the third vote to reopen the question.  Those reopen votes seem to have expired, and since the question isn't currently active, the only realistic path to reopening seems to be a post here on meta.

If the question were reopened, I would try to answer it by saying that the correctness of a paper, especially one containing a very complicated argument, is not a simple binary question, but lies on a continuum.  It is not unreasonable to draw attention to a published argument and suggest that it should be scrutinized by more people, digested properly by the community, and generalized or adapted to other problems if possible.  The trouble is that Yau has gone about this in an intentionally tactless manner, making Perelman's work seem more doubtful than it is, and courting controversy while disingenuously claiming to care only about the math.  In my answer, which I would make community wiki, I would also reproduce the mathematical content of some of the comments, which cite recent work that builds on Perelman's ideas.

Comment: I would be happy to vote to re-open if it were retitled to ask about the correctness of Yau's criticism and the long quote cut down to the bare essentials. A bunch of that looks like waffle or smokescreen (I mean, does Perelman wanting to wait for peer review to finish before explicitly claiming a proof somehow imply the proof might have errors? That's just good practice...)

Comment: My take on this is that the question on main needs to be either substantially rewritten (and retitled!) or, better, asked anew to make it clear and on-topic. From my viewpoint, it is really a question about history of math (and, by now, the entire affair is history). Just my 2 cents...

Comment: @DavidRoberts I was the one who typed in the full quote. What do you mean by cutting it down to the bare essentials? To properly evaluate what Yau says, one needs to see the polemical nature of his remarks (claiming to want to put the controversy behind him and then in the same breath making remarks that he admits are controversial, while claiming to care only about the math, etc.). If one cuts all that out then readers are left puzzled as to why other mathematicians are reacting so negatively to a call for more people to study Perelman's argument carefully.

Comment: @TimothyChow oh, ok, that makes sense.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have just attempted to rewrite the question. What do you think about it now?

Comment: @TimothyChow I think it's good, and I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @TimothyChow: This is much better now. One thing which still bothers me about the question in the current form: Most of what Yau says is not even a doubt in the proof. It's a sequence of lamentations such as "As far as I'm aware, no one has taken some of the techniques Perelman introduced toward the end of his paper and successfully used them to solve any other significant problem. This suggests to me that other mathematicians don't yet have full command of this work and its methodologies either." A valid answer has to address such lamentations as well.

Comment: @TimothyChow Maybe a bette phrasing would be "To what extent are the doubts and lamentations (?) about the current state of understanding of Perelman's proof well-founded?" Lastly, the original poster of the question was last seen at MO a week ago, which is another indication (to me) that this was not a serious inquiry. Given this, I think, it's OK to edit the question at will.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I agree that what you're calling "lamentations" should be addressed in the answer, but I prefer that the question itself be phrased as neutrally as possible, and the word "lamentation" is something of a pre-judgment. (By the way, as an aside, it seems that since I already voted to reopen a little while ago, I can't vote to reopen again for another couple of weeks.)

Comment: @TimothyChow: Ok, I will vote to reopen. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: I voted to delete the question, and here is why. There are several detailed published expositions of Perelman's work/program. The authors put their reputation on the line. Surely, this counts more than any MO answer could ever provide. Concerns with the above expositions should be first brought to the authors, or other experts. I gather this has not been tried because there is no specific concern. MO is not for idle speculations, imo. The question "Which other significant problems were solved via Ricci flow techniques of Perelman" is reasonable and no doubt would receive good answers.

Answer (score 6):

[REOPENED]

The question [Center of a monoid ring](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431058/center-of-a-group-ring) asks two questions, one of which can be found in standard texts and the other which is essentially an open question but which appears to be a harmless generalization of the first and that I believe from the comments was mistaken to be much easier than it is.

@AlexM, perhaps following my suggestion, removed the more basic question and left the more interesting one.

I would like to give a partial answer to the remaining question that explains in part why it is not as easy as you might first think.

Answer (score 5):

[REOPENED]

"[Find a TSP tour passing through at least one node in each set of nodes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/207867/6094)" was initially unclear, but the author
has now clarified it into a real question (and I corrected the English):
Is there a PTAS (polynomial-time approximation scheme) for this problem?

Answer (score 5):

[REOPENED]

The question [Lexicographic order on increasing $k$-tuples](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221076/lexicographic-order-on-increasing-k-tuples) by a first-time poster was closed as "unclear what you're asking".  I have rewritten it so that (I think) it is now clear.  It is not a hard question, but I think it probably has a nice answer.

Answer (score 5):

[REOPENED]

This question was heavily downvoted and closed: [When a compact topological manifold with boundary is a ball?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223311/when-a-compact-topological-manifold-with-boundary-is-a-ball) Color me ignorant, perhaps, but I wondered if it were as trivial as the downvotes and closure might suggest.

Although it is a question for the topological category, a very similar question but for the smooth category was upvoted and answered last year, and the answers suggested there was interesting mathematics: [The boundary of a domain whose interior is diffeomorphic to the ball](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158391/the-boundary-of-a-domain-whose-interior-is-diffeomorphic-to-the-ball).

**Update:** OP added some context.

Comment: The downvotes and closure do not necessarily suggest it is trivial. Rather they might just suggest the question is terribly written and thus deemed unsuitable, irrespective of its precise mathematical content. Let me add that I do not have a personal opinion on the content of this particular question (I also did not vote on it), but I am of the opinion that there are minimal standards on the presentation that should be enforced. It might be a good idea though to explain this when closing.

Comment: @quid We've both been here a long time. I said they *might* suggest that. No explanation is given, so we are left guessing what the problem actually  is. I don't think the question is *terribly* written; do you think that? If we tweaked it to read, "Let $X$ be a compact topological manifold with boundary, and suppose its interior is homeomorphic to an (open) ball. Is $X$ a (closed) ball?", then is it still terribly written? I wouldn't really think so.

Comment: Point taken on the "might."  The rewrite you propose is still a very poorly presented question, as it lacks all context and motivation. By contrast the well-received question you reference gives some context.

Comment: @quid There is ample precedent for short, snappy questions which don't include motivations/context, that have been well received. It is highly questionable whether questions that are short and snappy are ipso facto "poor". In any case, if this is the only objection, then I have to think that the reaction was likewise "poorly presented" (except perhaps for the possibility it does have a trivial answer I have overlooked).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, that's true. Many a complicated debate could have been avoided would there be only consensus that the official guide, which asks for context, on how to ask a question is somewhat binding (and to be sure that guide was written by "us" not SE).  Of course, a snappy question *can* "fly" and if it flies it might even fly higher than the same question with context. But, first, it is more fragile so to say. And also it does not alter the fact that it would still be a ultimately better question with some context even if it might get less upvotes.

Comment: @quid I added already a comment to the post suggesting adding some context. I can see the point of your last comment, but I think it would be hard getting community consensus on making it a *rule*.

Comment: I saw that comment. Thanks for adding it. To reply also to your second remark from the earlier comment: there is no disagreement there. I said right away 'It might be a good idea though to explain this when closing.' Certainly I am not blind to the fact that a closure without comment and the most generic reason is not optimal.

Comment: I don't agree at all the the presentation was particularly poor, and find it appalling that it got 5 downvotes and was closed within an hour.  It could have been written better, sure, but I strongly agree with Todd's remark that the question is self-motivating.

Comment: @EricWofsey  is the question better with or without the context?

Comment: @EricWofsey Agree with you very strongly. Again I would ask closers: if you are closing because you think the question is "not research level", then please please please take a moment to ask yourself whether you know enough about the subject to make that call. (If you don't, then leave it alone.) If the real reason for closure is that you think it's not well written, then please leave a note for the poor newcomer explaining how the post might be improved.

Comment: @quid: Obviously it is better with context, but that doesn't mean it was a bad question that needed to be put on hold, let alone put on hold with the swiftness and accompanying downvotes normally given only to calculus questions and their ilk.

Comment: I was one of the people voting to close.  I thought there were trivial counter-examples.  I realize now that my trivial counter-examples are not counter-examples.  My apologies to the OP.

Comment: @EricWofsey if what are in my opinion proper procedures would be followed this and related situations would go over much more smoothly. The users showing your type of reaction in such situations are in my firm opinion in the end not all that helpful either, but rather make a bad situation worse.

Answer (score 5):

[REOPENED]

The OP of this question [Connected sum is well-defined for surfaces, proof?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252868/connected-sum-is-well-defined-for-surfaces-proof) requests reconsideration to reopen. 
It was closed as a duplicate, but OP says that what is asked for was not answered at the other post; he/she wants a simple self-contained proof that doesn't invoke anything so powerful as the Annulus Theorem. OP believes that for the 2-dimensional case which is the focus here, there should be a simpler argument, and that's what is wanted. One of the comments below the question points out that with the classification of oriented surfaces in hand, well-definedness of connected sum is easy -- but insofar as the proof of the classification takes some build-up, I guess OP isn't satisfied with that either.

(I don't have a strong opinion here or a dog in the fight, but I did tell OP in response to a flag that I'd put it before the community at meta for consideration.)

Answer (score 4):

[REOPENED]

An ideal candidate to get things started is [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/134725/6085), **Preparing for set theory research**. I am definitely not happy with the wording, but I understand it may be very useful for beginning graduate students, and so it probably deserves a shot.

Answer (score 4):

[REOPENED]

I'd like to nominate [this question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200751/if-a-polynomial-pz-omits-a-value-then-pz-dfrac1-ei-psinzp-pr) It originally got closed due to a typo, which has been fixed. It's certainly not "unclear what you are asking" any more (the original reason for closing), and it looks like a perfectly reasonable question to me.

I have a (rather quick) answer ready, and it's mildly frustrating not to be able to post it.

Comment: The last reopen vote has been cast.

Answer (score 4):

The question
[A question on $p$-approximation property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179493/a-question-on-p-approximation-property) from 2014 has been automatically deleted owing to lack of upvotes. While I can't immediately tell if it is a good question, it seems a perfectly reasonable one, which is unlikely to attract bad or vague answers, and might eventually get a proper answer.

For those who have high enough rep to see the question, I suggest leaving your opinion in the comments.

[UNDELETED and REOPENED]

Comment: I cast the last vote to undelete and also voted up the question so it doesn't get autodeleted again.  Let me also link http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2232/should-we-try-to-re-start-manual-deletions-or-is-the-situation-fine-anyway/2245#2245 to again draw people's attention to this general issue.

Answer (score 4):

[REOPENED]

[Parameterizing rotations of a cube](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215407/parameterizing-rotations-of-a-cube)

was asked and answered, but I don't see a reason for closing it.

Comment: I think you're right, Gil, but I'll wait for another vote to reopen before applying moderator power.

Comment: I cast a vote to reopen mainly as I do not see the point of such "after the fact closure." We are not going to delete the post, are we? // @ToddTrimble there is only one vote missing now.

Answer (score 4):

[REOPENED]

I'd like to suggest reopening [Covering systems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253250/covering-systems). As I wrote in a comment,

Why is this closed? Covering systems are a recognized area of research in Number Theory. It's known that in an irredundant cover with a modulus divisible by a prime $p$
 there are at least $p$
 moduli divisible by $p$. This asks whether, if there is a modulus divisible by a power of a prime $p$, there are at least $p$
 moduli divisible by that power of $p$. Seems like a reasonable research question to me.

[Also, I think I can answer it.]

Comment: I've just cast a 5th vote to reopen. Let's see if anyone who voted to close leaves further comments

Answer (score 4):

[Undeleted; Reopened]

[If normal with respect to prime base then normal for all bases](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/260442/if-normal-with-respect-to-prime-base-then-normal-for-all-bases) was closed as not being research math. I nominated it for reopening, after leaving a comment establishing its research content. There were four votes to reopen; then, OP chose to delete the question.

So now I am asking for the question to be undeleted and, should that happen, for it to be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED]

I think people were pretty hasty in shutting down this question: [Shape of axioms in abstract algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137640/shape-of-axioms-in-abstract-algebra). I could just barely squeeze in some highly relevant content and context in a comment before the thing was shut down. I request that this be reopened.

Comment: I had voted to migrate to math.SE, since I think the question is a fine, but a better match for them, but it seems that migration was not the actual result. Is it still possible to migrate a question that has been placed on hold? If not, I guess I'll vote to reopen, especially if Todd has something to say.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: moderators could still migrate it. If you would like this, just flag the question with a moderator attention flag giving this request as the reason for flagging. (This is to answer the technical question, I have no opinion on this question.)

Comment: I have suggested an edit which may place the question more properly in the realm of mathoverflow.stackexchange.  It is still on the naive side, although one can find answers on the lines of finding mostly equational bases for theories which include or may be included by the definition theory.

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED]

[Boundary conditions for Klein-Gordon equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242971/boundary-conditions-for-klein-gordon-equation)

The author has responded to comments and edited the question into a form that is much clearer, and in fact bringing it into the realm of active research. Just need 2 more re-open votes last I checked.

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED]

The question [Identify one group of linear transformations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268710/) was closed as "unclear what you're asking". Afterwards it has been edited and clarified. I don't see what is still "unclear" in this question.

Answer (score 3):

[UNDELETED]

I propose that this question should be undeleted:
[Reduced ring with all non-prime ideals finitely generated](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304492/reduced-ring-with-all-non-prime-ideals-finitely-generated)

It was deleted by the OP despite having a substantial answer by Keith Kearnes.  Keith has re-asked the question and re-posted his answer at
[Reduced ring with all non-prime ideals finitely generated](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304533/reduced-ring-with-all-non-prime-ideals-finitely-generated)

Comment: About the concerned post: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3798/deleted-answered-question

Comment: Update: undeleted by the OP; re-post became redundant and in turn deleted by Keith.

Answer (score 3):

[[UNDELETED] [REOPENED] [CLOSED]](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/328312/revisions)

I would suggest to undelete/reopen https://mathoverflow.net/q/328312, as a courtesy and sign of respect, and then hopefully one of our experts can answer it.

<sub>I know, I was one of those who cast a vote to delete, when I was still under the impression that this was posted under a false name. Somehow the software allows to retract close votes but not delete votes.</sub>

*Edit GRP 2019.07.11*  The question was deleted by community user on May 23. I think it should be undeleted as it makes an excellent example of how to not ask a question on MathOverflow. It can also be used to help design a format for others to follow in asking questions suitable for this forum. I also reference it in one of my posts on meta. *End Edit*

Comment: I find some of the comments on that question extremely, extremely dispiriting. What happened to the MathOverflow I knew where people acted with some charity towards fellow researchers who maybe, just maybe, did not have the same undergraduate education or simply do not have the time to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I should explain that I am more likely to downvote or vote-to-close a question which seems to be on topic X by a student in X who should be finding the answer to a question on X as part of their studies of X. Whereas a specialist in Y asking a question on X that people who study X can answer easily was **surely one of the original princples/purposes of MO**

Comment: @Yemon, Sympathetic as I am with your position, we still lack a standard of how researchers in Y can ask questions about X. I am still surprised at the way this question was posted, and find it hard to distinguish from a question asked by student X who has not tried even a Google search. Perhaps you can think of a better way to handle this?  Gerhard "What If Asker Is Unreal?" Paseman, 2019.04.17.

Comment: My opinion (visibly not shared by some of you) is that I think the rules should aim at being the same for all people and acted regardless of the possible (now verified) identity.

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED]

[This cw question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167849/correct-spelling-of-names-chebyshev-and-cholesky/) (on the spelling of Chebyshev and Cholesky) has good answers and I think it deserves to be reopened. (The sole Chebyshev case was worth a specific discussion, and for this reason I think it's fine to have it here rather than on a linguistics forum.)

Answer (score 3):

[REOPENED]

[**Why did Bourbaki ignore the theory of categories?**](//mathoverflow.net/questions/131657/why-did-bourbaki-ignore-the-theory-of-categories) only survived 25 hours in 2013, collecting 5 answers; it has been closed ever since. The reason given (“not constructive”, “will likely solicit debate, arguments,...” rather than “facts, references,...”) would no longer be an option, and seems refuted by the [facts](//mathoverflow.net/questions/131657/why-did-bourbaki-ignore-the-theory-of-categories#comment585277_131657), [references](//mathoverflow.net/questions/131657/why-did-bourbaki-ignore-the-theory-of-categories#comment846405_131738), [etc.](//mathoverflow.net/questions/131657/why-did-bourbaki-ignore-the-theory-of-categories#comment846599_131657) since added in low-visibility comments.

While not intent on writing an answer myself, I don’t think it would hurt to clear the way for others to do so. (As of now, there are 4 votes to reopen, so only 1 more is needed — until they expire.)

Answer (score 3):

[[UNDELETED](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/4519/revisions)]

I propose to undelete my question:

[Something like mathoverflow in other sciences](https://mathoverflow.net/q/4519)

It was asked in the early days of MO and has some useful links and information. I Have no idea why some people wanted to delete it 11 months ago.

Answer (score 3):

Status: [REOPENED] Thank you!

Request to reopen [How to obtain the rational solution of a linear system efficiently?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/349540).

In light of recent discussions about being more welcoming to good faith questions from less experienced users, I believe this is an example of a question that was too quickly closed and not given due consideration. I had previously voted to reopen right after writing my answer, but it hadn't garnered enough attention then.

Answer (score 3):

[A chess question of W.T. Tutte](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107385/a-chess-question-of-w-t-tutte/226893?noredirect=1#comment970737_226893) has been closed for at least 5 years. The only argument given for its closure at the time was that a moderator saw it as a question of chess strategy. I think the first phrasing was not clear. Most of the answers (including the green-ticked one) are indeed "chess answers".

However, it is not a question of chess strategy, it is a mathematics question, and my reply (14 upvotes currently) reports on a novel non-constructive result which is not limited to chess, but can apply to any game where widespread strategy-stealing is possible.

Looking through the page of guidelines as to why else this question might be marked "off-topic", the only thing which caught my eye is whether this is an "open question". It seems impossible to prove the largest question: that chess is not a win for Black. However there are many easier related Combinatorial Game Theory ideas, including scope strategy-stealing, symmetric zugzwangs, transition between hot & cold games and possibly random games.

Please can you re-open this question, and un-green-tick the current accepted answer (which has just 2 upvotes). Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know only the original asker can untick the accepted answer. This remark would have to be posed as a request in a comment on the question itself. I don't know if the closed status of the question interferes with the OP's ability to do so, though.

Comment: The original asker was last seen on MathOverflow in March of 2018, so unaccepting may be asking too much.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments. If it's problematic to unaccept, I suppose I would say it's kind of secondary - the main request is to unclose the question, please.

Comment: Upvoted and voted to reopen; I enjoyed reading Andrew's contribution, and while I agree that open questions should be avoided this question is labeled as a reference request; the OP isn't looking for an answer to the open problem, only the most cutting edge literature which I think is a) an appropriate question for combinatorial game theorists and b) provided by Andrew's answer as far as I can tell.

Comment: So... what's happening now? Forget about the accepted answer. The question remains closed. This is all very opaque and unsatisfactory. Please can any moderator who reads this and feels it should *not* be reopened can reply here to explain their position. Thank you

Comment: You keep referring to "moderators", Andrew. So far as I can see, no moderator has had anything to do with the question. The comments, and the five votes to close, all came from ordinary users, not from moderators. The moderators of this site are generally reluctant to get involved in matters that can be settled by users. I'm out of suggestions as to what to do next. Sometimes, you do your best, and lose anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Gerry. So there's no reason why the closers should visit here. How close are we to unclosing it? All I can think to add is some info about Bill Tutte himself. He wasn't just one of the founders of graph theory, he was one of the heroes of British code-breaking. When I visited Bletchley Park, I saw an exhibition dedicated to Tutte's achievements. As one website says: "Alan Turing cracked the Enigma Code *with* knowledge of what the technology looked like, Bill [Tutte] cracked the Lorenz Code *without* knowledge of what the technology looked like and how it worked."

Answer (score 3):

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379145/geometric-combinatorial-problem-in-the-euclidean-space

This question was deleted by nobody less than @ToddTrimble just 10 days ago after having 9 upvotes and a few answers. The problem is neither ridiculous, nor fully resolved, and I see absolutely nothing out of the ordinary with either the question itself, or any of the answers, so I'm quite curious if it was a deletion by mistake or something sinister is going on here.

Comment: Probably it is worth reminding that an answer which was deleted *by a moderator* cannot be undeleted by regular users. (But I suppose you're aware of this - if you tried to cast an undelete vote, you saw a pop-up explaining this.)

Comment: Yep, I know that. That's why I also tried to attract the attention of @ToddTrimble to it though I'm not really sure if the at symbol works in the answer body. Any other moderator would do too :-)

Comment: You may want to flag Todd (flag any of his comments anywhere). No idea if this happened here, but it could be it was deleted by mistake.

Comment: I have responded here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56897449#56897449 I understand why the situation seems confusing, but it was not deleted by mistake, and there was nothing sinister going on. The other moderators can see what happened as well.

Comment: This reminded me of another question that I was surprised to see deleted by a moderator, despite of several answers with upvotes. I even suspect it might be the same author (I noticed they tend to delete their questions quite a bit). https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376821

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

A question [Finite groups with no elements of order $p^2q$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135264/element-of-p2q-free-order) originally closed was heavily edited by Yves Cornulier and Nick Gill.

There are three votes to reopen already, but the question is already a bit out of sight, thus this posting.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

The question

[Finding all local maximum points of a function?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139700/finding-all-local-maximum-points-of-a-function)

does not seem as trivial to me as has been supposed. Sure, one can set the gradient equal to zero, but how does one actually prove that the only solutions are the "obvious ones"? At the very least it seems worth leaving the question open for a while.

Answer (score 2):

[A couple of questions about Turing machines that are bounded in space but have an infinite amount of time in which to operate](https://mathoverflow.net/q/143191).

I think some votes to close here were due confusion related to an [earlier version of the question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142986/a-question-or-two-about-turing-machines-that-are-bounded-in-space-but-not-limite) where the OP experienced technical difficulties. The objection that the OP's SBTMs are finite state machines is incorrect. Moreover, SBTMs are not completely ad hoc or unmotivated, the computer you are using to read this sentence is essentially an SBTM.

Comment: **The objection that the OP's SBTMs are finite state machines is incorrect.** Why? Perhaps we are interpreting the definitions differently?

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

I think this question:[Are there infinitely many natural numbers not covered by one of these 7 polynomials?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164792/are-there-infinitely-many-natural-numbers-not-covered-by-one-of-these-7-polynomi) should be reopened.  Please see the comments by me and Joel in main.

Comment: I think the question in its current form is actually quite bad, but the additions from the comments by the OP help. Specifically, it asks how he can prove something that he only suspects to be true, rather than asking whether it is true. And with no further details, the question is way too specific (I mean, if I was to ask the same question about the same polynomials except I change one coefficient in one of them, why would that not also be an equally good question?)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft:  I think if you change the coefficients it would still be an interesting question, as I mention in my comment.  The general question, of which the original one is a special case, is unclear to me.  The current question is clearly stated, and the answer is not at all obvious.  You may not be interested in the question, which is fine, but note that the question was closed as being not up to research level (without indicating any answer).

Comment: I agree that the general type of question is of interest. But focusing on a special case is not unless that special case has some additional property, either coming from something else or for some reason being "generic". An answer to this question that would not work for any other set of polynomials at all would for example be completely uninteresting, but answer the question.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I think you are wrong here, but of course you are entitled to your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The question [How to find generators to Mordell weil groups of elliptic curves?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179673/how-to-find-generators-to-mordell-weil-groups-of-elliptic-curves) was originally phrased in the narrow context of inquiring just about the software Sage.  I had voted to close that, but the revised more general question seems worth reopening.  I have cast my vote to reopen, but am not sure that the revised question has received enough attention.

(Also, this meta question now has too many answers, and perhaps it's better to start a new thread with the same intent.  When I wrote this reopen request, the system wanted to know if with 30 answers to this question whether I really wanted to add another one.)

[REOPENED]

Comment: I would say that a message popping up when you post an answer is a small price to pay for having everything gathered one place.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

The question [Isomorphism problem for two radical extensions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188165/isomorphism-problem-for-two-radical-extensions) originally had an error in its formulation.  This was subsequently corrected by OP, and the question seems quite interesting and has attracted good answers (including one that somehow came in after the question was closed!).  I think it should be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

This question [If $\binom{2p}{p}$ is $(-1)^{p-1} \bmod 2p+1$ is then $2p+1$ prime?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209110/if-binom2pp-is-1p-1-bmod-2p1-is-then-2p1-prime) was mistakenly closed (by me, among others).  I have cast my vote to reopen.  The question has been answered in interesting comments by Robert Israel and YCor.

Answer (score 2):

[UNDELETED]

The question 
[Generalized arithmetic progressions contained in Bohr sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204356/generalized-arithmetic-progressions-contained-in-bohr-sets) looks reasonable and did not attract any negative comments or downvotes. I propose that it should be undeleted

Answer (score 2):

[UNDELETED]

The question [On isolated points of the approximate point spectrum of a bounded operator](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204283/on-isolated-points-of-the-approximate-point-spectrum-of-a-bounded-operator) looks reasonable and did not attract any negative comments or downvotes. I propose that it should be undeleted.

Answer (score 2):

[REOPENED]

[Basic Definition and Notations in RWRE](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243062/basic-definition-and-notations-in-rwre) is exactly what it says: a question about definitions and notation used in the study of random walk in random environment (RWRE) within probability theory.   This is a very active research area, with a rather specific and idiosyncratic vocabulary and notation which can certainly be challenging for newcomers to the topic.  These notions are not part of the standard graduate probability curriculum; at best one might see them in an advanced special topics course.

I think this question is certainly research level and should be reopened.  I left a comment to that effect which has 4 upvotes.  The question itself also has 4 upvotes and 0 downvotes.

Comment: I agree with Nate and have voted to undelete

Answer (score 2):

[[REOPENED](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/292788/revisions)]

I would like to request to reopen [Relation between the Hochschild cohomology of group algebras and groupoids](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292788/relation-between-the-hochschild-cohomology-of-group-algebras-and-groupoids). The original question was very vague, but it has since been edited and is now, in my opinion, a perfectly fine question.

Comment: BTW it seems that the question is at the moment still in the [reopen review queue](https://mathoverflow.net/review/reopen/94984). (It already [went through review once](https://mathoverflow.net/review/reopen/94926) with 3 votes to leave closed - however that was before the most recent edit.)

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135355/prove-well-known-theorem-by-jean-pierre-serre), which started out extremely confused, is now a well defined question asking for a sketch of a proof of a theorem of Serre in differential geometry. Probably not a great question, but it seems like the sort of question we would have accepted if it were asked in this form to begin with, so I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>[REOPENED]</strike>

Please have a look at the comments at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135605/how-to-discover-counterexamples-and-required-objects? and consider voting to reopen.

Comment: On a procedural note: why is this (already) posted here, when the question had already its own meta question? (In addition to being still on the frontpage, even now hours later, so it was presumably fairly to the top when this was posted.)

Comment: @quid, I didn't see that meta question. There was no link to it at the original, and nothing in the name of the meta question to draw my attention to its relevance here. Shall I withdraw this question?

Comment: thank you for the reply. I do not think it is necessary to withdraw this post now. My comment was also meant to help form some consensus when one should post here. I take you reply as you agreeing with me that in principle one should rather not do so in parallel with an existing meta-disussion on the question. I agree the meta-question in this case was hard to notice, which I tried to fix now, before even noticing you reply.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/136716/6085), on a *geometric inequality*, was closed due to its poor original wording. After the edit, it appears to be a reasonable problem.

Comment: The question was closed not due to its poor original wording but because the author intentionally concealed information about known results (some published, some not), relevant numerical evidence, etc., apparently in order to issue a "challenge".  I think it's great that Andres has edited the question to add this information but as long as the OP has made no effort to cooperate, or acknowledge Andres's efforts, I am reluctant to vote to reopen.

Comment: There's of course a good argument for saying that we want good questions wherever they come from.  But there's a countervailing good argument for saying that bad behavior will tend to get your question closed.

Comment: (I agree with Steven.)

Comment: As the question stands now it is a blatant nonsense--the sum of points on a unit circle $\ S,\ $ centered at $\ 0\ $ is not $\ 0,\ $ not in general. Consider $\ n=1.\ $ or any positive $\ n.$

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

The question

[The probability for a streak when tossing a coin](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140080/the-probability-for-a-streak-when-tossing-a-coin)

was closed quickly, but as far as I know, this is not an exercise. There is a complicated approximation in Feller's classic text.

As suggested in this question, I put more discussion in [a separate thread](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/678/should-the-probability-for-a-streak-when-tossing-a-coin-be-reopened).

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[Question on a concrete example of n points](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140776/question-on-a-concrete-example-of-n-points) has been improved considerably since it was closed and might be considered for re-opening.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

The question [Proving $\sum_{k=0}^{2m}(-1)^k{\binom{2m}{k}}^3=(-1)^m\binom{2m}{m}\binom{3m}{m}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143334/proving-sum-k-02m-1k-binom2mk3-1m-binom2mm-binom3mm) was closed as "off-topic." As far as I can tell, it is reasonable, and of interest to many as shown by the answer, upvotes, comments, and favorites. Quite a few mathematicians find this identity interesting, don't know Dixon's Theorem, and would take a while to prove it on their own.

I added a tag and rewrote the request for help to look a little more professional. I don't think that those should be grounds for closing. They are reasons to edit the question or perhaps vote it down, but not to block others from answering the question.

Comment: Isn't the idea of being "on hold" (rather than "closed") *precisely* so these changes you suggest are implemented? Once the changes are in place, and things appear reasonable, reopening it is the natural course of action. (This is the same idea behind closing votes being reversible, isn't it?)

Comment: You do not need to close a question in order to add a relevant tag, or to make a minor change. Closing this question blocked Mark Wildon from answering it. How does that help?

Comment: (The question has been reopened, by the way. The last opening vote was mine.) I agree, but some people feel it should be the OP who carries out these changes.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

The question [Square of primary ideals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149713/square-of-primary-ideals) was originally closed as being "unclear what you're asking", but after the edit I don't think this is a valid reason anymore. (I'm no expert here, but it seems like a reasonable question to me.)

Answer (score 1):

[reopened]

**Edit** I edited the question.

---

I think that the question

[How to construct a group with specified growth function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151165/how-to-construct-a-group-and-the-corresponding-manifold-with-specified-growth-fu)

Is not an unreasonable question and I don't fully see why it is closed. The English is not optimal and no motivation is given, but it is not alone in that respect.  The basic underlying question is reasonable (note also that the OP, based on previous questions, seems to come from formal language theory, not group theory).  The basic question is whether there is some procedure (perhaps algorithmic) to construct groups with a prescribed growth function.

Of course, constructing groups with intermediate growth is a difficult problem and I don't even think there is a procedure in general for semigroups (except one by Bergman for certain growth ranges).  Work like http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0262 is to some extent concerned with variations of this question.

So I think it is reasonable to leave it open even if a complete answer seems out of reach.

Comment: I agree that one could ask a reasonable question about prescribing the growth of groups.  However, this is not it.  For instance, I don't know what the OP means by "manifold", and I don't know exactly what the OP means with regards to a growth function, e.g. what's the equivalence relation?  For instance, as written he might have a specific function and want a group with a specific finite generating set realizing that specific function on the nose.  Someone (either you or the OP) should rewrite the question before it is reopened.

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

I asked in a [separate thread](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2212/probability-question-migrated-to-stats-stackexchange?noredirect=1#comment10218_2212) about the closing of the question 
[a question on 0-1 valued stochastic process](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/202242/revisions), located at [a question on 0-1 valued stochastic process](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202242/a-question-on-0-1-valued-stochastic-process), and it was suggested that here would be the good place to bring it up.

The question was closed very speedily - I'm not particularly sure why. It's surely not a very exciting question, and I think it has a fairly straightforward answer, but it seems reasonable for someone to ask. I wouldn't be surprised if a colleague asked me it in the department. Anyway, I don't have strong feelings; but I am surprised that the question was migrated to stats.stackexchange, since as far as I can see, it isn't even on-topic there - that site is supposedly for "statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization" (although possibly the usage is broader than that definition).

Comment: It appears that the migration to stats was rejected.

Comment: Actually, the stats mod reported that it would have been on-topic for their site, but also that it might fare better at MO if it were reopened. It is currently on hold at MO and could be reopened with five votes. Incidentally, James, is this a question you'd be prepared to answer?

Comment: As a stats.SE moderator, I can confirm @Todd's comment regarding this question being on-topic at stats. We'll consider clarifying the scope a little bit on our help pages. Thanks for mentioning it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

[UNDELETED]

The question

[Does there exist some $C$ independent of $n$ and $f$ such that $ \|f''\|_p \geq Cn^2 \| f \|_p$, where $1 \leq p\leq \infty$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231179/)

seemed decent enough and had a good answer from Christian Remling, but was deleted by its author. Do we have a standard policy here for self-deleted posts?

Comment: An answer (http://mathoverflow.net/a/231246/) has been reinstated, and Remling claims the previous answer was wrong.

Comment: For the record: I am not sure about a standard policy, but  excepting unusual circumstances  including  noticeable spite or vandalism (inapplicable in this case), I can see little reason not to just accept the author's wishes regarding the status of their answer. There is a reason self-deletes do not even show up in the standard list of deleted posts.

Comment: @quid: my issue wasn't with the deletion of the answer, but the deletion of the question

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood this, in part due to the preceding comment. For deletion of questions, I would say the same, except if it is unmotivated and/or deletes valuable answers in the process. This case is rare as the software is by now very rigid in this regard (this used to be more flexible). A delete of a question with answer is only possible if there is only one answer and this answer has no upvote (note it really no upvote, not positive score). This question however seems to have fallen in that segment, and I tend to support the undelete here. (But if in doubt I'd  respect OP's intent.)

Comment: Minor correction: "if it deletes valuable answers and is not clearly motivated" is closer to what I want to say.

Answer (score 1):

[UNDELETED]

[Unreasonable application of mathematics to the other areas](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/243030/unreasonable-application-of-mathematics-to-the-other-areas/243033#243033)

I may be biased, but the deletion of this question, together with both its answers [and Todd's very pertinent correction], seems an overly drastic action, which I would suggest to undo.

The SE deletion policy, *"a post that no longer adds anything to the site should be deleted"* does not seem quite applicable here.

Comment: I agree.  Closing a question still leaves it visible, and deleting seems uncalled for except in extreme cases.

Comment: It's not clear to me why answers to the question in question can't just be posted as answers to the earlier linked question 61408.

Comment: @GerryMyerson --- I don't know of a way to transfer answers + comment thread from one question to another (put perhaps the moderators have this capability); in any case, I thought that closing rather than deleting the question is the way to proceed with duplicates, isn't this how we have always done it?

Comment: What I had in mind, Carlo, was that the people who posted to the one thread could just copy their posts and paste them on the other. Or, someone (you?) could do that for them (giving full credit, of course, and making the answers CW, if desired). But, yes, I think that moderators can do that for questions closed as duplicates. Once the answers are transferred, by whatever means, I'd think the one question could be deleted, no harm done.

Comment: @Gerry (and Carlo) Moderators do have the power to merge questions after one is closed as the duplicate of the other. I imagine this functionality is less known since there is simply less call for it on this site. Merging question will delete and lock one of the copies and transfer all comments/answers to the other copy. It is actually used quite a bit on Math.SE.

Answer (score 1):

[[UNDELETED](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/277564/revisions)] - but at the moment still closed – but now redeleted.

The question

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277564/computer-aided-investigation-of-zeta-anyone-has-input

is about a certain inequality for the Riemann zeta function which, if true (in a certain domain), is stronger than the RH (in that domain). The question is if this or related inequalities were considered before or about any other insights regarding it. This looks like a good research level question and I don't understand why it was closed or deleted. I propose to undelete and open it.

**Update:** The question was answered in the comments and I propose to keep it close but not to delete it.

Comment: I've voted to undelete. In the question he links to a preprint of his in the General Mathematics section of the arXiv called "A study of the Riemann zeta function" and he has another preprint there called "A study of Fermat's last theorem". Now, a brief look didn't suggest that either was crankery, but I can understand how people might jump to that conclusion.

Comment: About your update: "The question was answered in the comments and I propose to keep it close but not to delete it." This is not really possible unless the question gains some upvotes. A question with negative score and no answer is deleted after 30 days - unless the mods lock the post. Some details are [listed in help](https://mathoverflow.net/help/roomba) and further details can be found in [the links listed here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/auto-delete/info).

Comment: @Martin, indeed, the question has been redeleted by "Community".

Answer (score 1):

[Deleted]

I believe that
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279453/
deserves re-opening, so that the OP can clarify or engage. It might be that the notion of magnitude for metric spaces, for instance, is one that could be relevant for the OP.

---

Following a reminder from Martin that not everyone can see the original question: here it is in its entirety.

> I would like to measure the diversity of a finite (but large) set of points in a metric space.
>
> The average distance does not work, because if the points are concentrated near 2 locations (say, 0 and 1), then the set is not diverse, although the average distance is near 1/2

In comments, the OP goes on to add

> I did not find a good formal definition: using the variance or the entropy does not work: a Bernouilli process switching between 2 points has high entropy, but is not 'diverse' intuitively. Taking the geometric mean instead of the arithmetic mean does not improve the situation

Comment: If some people under 10k are curious what the question is about and cannot see it since it is currently deleted, I will mention that at the moment you can still see the question [in Google Cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279453/in-a-metric-space-how-to-measure-the-diversity-of-a-set-of-points).

Comment: OP was able to clarify or engage while the question was closed (until it was deleted, but that was over a week later).

Comment: I'd vote to undelete and reopen if the OP states here the intention to edit and clarify the question. On the other hand, I don't think it makes sense to re-activate an abandoned question.

Comment: I have [pinged the OP](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221468/when-the-composition-of-two-ergodic-maps-is-ergodic#comment694070_221468) on another question. So maybe he will joint the discussion here and say whether the question is still of interest and whether they can add some further clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

**Re-opened and then re-closed**

I don't think it is obvious how to find the shortest chord that bisects
the area of a convex polygon. That is the question posed in this now closed post: [Shortest bisecting line](https://mathoverflow.net/q/312824/6094).
Perhaps one would have to use the algorithm below, modified to spin the direction
through $180^\circ$.

> Shermer, Thomas C. "A linear algorithm for bisecting a polygon." *Information Processing Letters* 41, no. 3 (1992): 135-140.

Answer (score 1):

The question
[Why do some mathematicians believe that the notation $(x_n)_{n\in \omega}$ is better than $(x_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ or $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313578/why-do-some-mathematicians-believe-that-the-notation-x-n-n-in-omega-is-be) seems to be asked in good faith, even if the tone may have annoyed people who use the notation. It was closed as "primarily opinion-based" but I think that actual practitioners, especially those who work with the von Neumann model/definition of the ordinals, could have sensible answers from which we might all learn something.

I don't use this notation myself, but I have a joint paper where at least one of the co-authors does use this notation.

I think the question deserves to be re-opened and taken seriously.

Comment: Maybe part of the reason for closure is that the question has been asked anonymously, by a user-xyz.

Comment: @jeq this is a tangent, but I don't think the inference "So Occam's Razor tells us that this unregistered user is already a known contributor to Math Overflow" is justified. Plenty of people who are English-speaking academics may have been aware of MO but not actually contributed before asking

Comment: "deleted by Community♦ yesterday (RemoveAbandonedClosed)" so if it gets undeleted, it will just be redeleted unless it gets some upvotes and/or gets reopened and gets some upvoted answers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the reminder. If you look at the question it had a lot of early negative votes but also then some later upvotes

Comment: At the moment, users below 10k still can see some version of the post [in the Google Cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313578/why-do-some-mathematicians-believe-that-the-notation-x-n-n-in-omega-is-be+). (However, 10k+ users can check that some votes and comments cam after that version. If I understand correctly how Google Cache works, this version will be no longer be shown after Google crawls that page the next time .)

Comment: It seems that the question was [posted from an unregistered account](https://mathoverflow.net/users/130430/user563454) and the user what not online since the day they posted the question here, it's not clear whether they are still interested in this. This is probably for a longer discussion, but perhaps a possible alternative would be if somebody else posts a new question; with a link to deleted one - to give credit; and also with a more detailed explanation why the question is interesting - to prevent closure.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the question will be treated differently if it is not posted by a new user. (Or I could suggest posting on Mathematics - but I know that Yemon Choi does not have an account there, so in this specific instance it is a less optimal choice.)

Comment: It doesn't look deleted to me. Odd.

Comment: @DavidRoberts well, someone or something has reopened it at some point between my edit and your comment :)

Comment: (It's been undeleted but not reopened.)

Answer (score 1):

[REOPENED]

[How slowly can it takes for the Fibonacci terms in a partially permutative self-distributive algebra to stabilize?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/289272/22277)

**How slowly can it takes for the Fibonacci terms in a partially permutative self-distributive algebra to stabilize?**

If $(X,*)$ satisfies the self-distributivity law $x*(y*z)=(x*y)*(x*z)$, then define an action of the positive braid monoid $B_{n}^{+}$ on $X^{n}$ by letting
$$(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})\cdot \sigma_{i}=(x_{1},\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i}*x_{i+1},x_{i},x_{i+2},\dots,x_{n}).$$ Then $(X,*)$ is *partially permutative* if for each pair $x,y\in X$, there is some $n$ where $(x,y)\cdot\sigma_{1}^{n}=(x,y)\cdot\sigma_{1}^{n+2},(x,y)\cdot\sigma_{1}^{n+1}=(x,y)\cdot\sigma_{1}^{n+3}$ and if $(x,y)\cdot\sigma_{1}^{n}=(r,s)$, then
$(x,y)\cdot\sigma_{1}^{n+1}=(s,r)$.

The motivation behind partially permutative self-distributive algebras is that the quotient algebras of elementary embeddings $\mathcal{E}_{\lambda}/\equiv^{\gamma}$ are always partially permutative (and much more) and because the action of $B_{n}^{+}$ on $X^{n}$ is simplified whenever $(X,*)$ is partially permutative.

I asked this question since I wonder how long it will take for the sequence $((x,y)\cdot\sigma_{1}^{n})_{n\in\omega}$ to stabilize if we know the cardinality of $X$.

Under large cardinal assumptions, we know that for all $N$, there is a finite partially permutative algebra $(X,*)$ and $x,y\in X$ where $((x,y)\cdot\sigma_{1}^{n})_{n\in\omega}$ takes more than $N$ steps to stabilize, but I do not know if one can remove the large cardinal hypotheses from this result.

Answer (score 1):

Status: [REOPENED]

Request to reopen [What is the endgoal of formalising mathematics?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378473/what-is-the-endgoal-of-formalising-mathematics)

I think it's a good question about an important contemporary evolution of mathematics and found the few arguments to close it not really convincing. It attracted several good answers so far.

Answer (score 0):

[Deleted by the OP]

I wonder if we were too quick to close https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137103/proving-finite-representation-of-integers-in-irrational-bases --- from one of the comments, it appears that this may be research-level mathematics.

Comment: Certainly I was hasty, but my goat was got somewhat by "phinary" and "Cantor dust"; also @ARupinski's comment seems to suggest insufficient thought put in by the OP.

Comment: @Yemon, certainly some cases are easy, and there was no indication OP had thought through them. But it looks like there is some meat on that bone.

Comment: I made the comment referred to above.  As in a further comment I made on the original question, I think the question should be made more precise before reopening.

Comment: Also, more generally, is it worth making a comment or edit to original questions to alert people to the discussion here?

Comment: @Carl, I've added a comment to the question (although it will only alert people who look at the question).

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

[An integral representation of the Riemann zeta function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140696/an-integral-representation-of-the-riemann-zeta-function) was closed, with commenters asking for more information. Author has now supplied the requested information. Perhaps the question should be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

The question on [Contraction mapping principle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146864/contraction-mapping-principle) was recently closed, but it is not a clear case of off-topic question. I thought it would be good to bring it up here for consideration.

Comment: Perhaps not clearly off-topic, but it does look like a peculiar question to me. I am guessing OP saw the stated theorem ("Th.") in a book or paper somewhere and wants to know what it's good for. It would help to know what book or paper it was, so that some needed context could be divined.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

I think the following question looks reasonable to me:
[Bussgang theorem for cyclostationary processes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/148509/)

It was closed as "unclear what you're asking". But with all due respect to those who voted to close, I don't think most of them are very familiar with cyclo-stationary processes - I could easily imagine the question being completely clear and unambiguous to someone actually working in this area.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the question [Hom-set with functions and arguments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211470/hom-set-with-functions-as-arguments) as requested to be self contained and clear.

( I asked the question very late last night and only was able to fix it this morning  in the UK.  )

UPDATE: The question never got reopened, and has since been deleted.

Comment: Dear Henry, I undeleted your question but it is up to the community to reopen it.

Comment: Re-deleted 1 September 2015.

Answer (score 0):

[Mathematicians who were late learners?-list](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3591/mathematicians-who-were-late-learners-list)

Reason: How is this no longer relevant or specific to a certain geographical area or time? It is a valid history question. That can't be specific to a certain geographical area or time. I think this is a very interesting question; likely to help, or at least interest other users. Therefore think it makes no sense for this question to be closed, so I request it to be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

[UNDELETED] (and upvoted to prevent redeletion)

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186186/characterization-of-global-sections-which-are-not-products-of-a-sheaf-which-is) does not seem unreasonable to me, and did not attract any votes or comments before it was auto-deleted. Perhaps it simply did not catch people's attention?

Comment: I voted to undelete on the general principle that questions with no downvotes and which were not closed should not be auto-deleted.  If a third person votes to undelete, they should perhaps vote the question up or the same thing will happen again.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

I'd like to reopen [When does $\nabla\times(\nabla\times F)=0$ imply $\nabla \times F=0$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226403/when-does-nabla-times-nabla-times-f-0-imply-nabla-times-f-0) . It is a clearly stated question, and seems like it has some interesting connections to differential topology.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

{as of Mon Apr 11 15:03:06 UTC 2016}

The CW question [Examples of math hoaxes/interesting jokes published on April Fool's day?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235008/examples-of-math-hoaxes-interesting-jokes-published-on-april-fools-day) was posted on 2016-04-01.

It has score of 69, 43 favorites and was answered by moderator.

I think it is too young to die and probably will edit, suggesting not to promote it to active on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

[Re-opened] then [Re-closed]

Request to reopen [Linear systems of equations with singular coefficient matrix](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239995/linear-systems-of-equations-with-singular-coefficient-matrix).

This question has been mostly rewritten and has now 4 reopen votes, besides two answers.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

I feel that the decision about closing my question:

[Euclid vs Eratosthenes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243126/euclid-vs-eratosthenes)

was arbitrary. I hope that it will be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

The question [product distinct prime factors of prime(n)-1 and prime(n)+1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242997/product-distinct-prime-factors-of-primen-1-and-primen1) has been closed as "unclear". I edited in a suggested clarification, and OP has indicated that my edit conveys OP's intentions. Please consider voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

I nominate [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256638/the-nth-power-of-a-matrix-by-companion-matrix) because it is not clear to me why it should be off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

The OP of [Comparison of the classical Fourier transform and the Fourier-Mukai transform](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109127/comparison-of-the-classical-fourier-transform-and-the-fourier-mukai-transform) made an edit two days ago to add more focus to the question, and requests reconsideration. There are currently two votes to reopen the question, but since it has fallen off the front page, other users might not have noticed.

Answer (score 0):

[DELETED]

I think that between the editing and the comments [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261549/how-to-reallocate-one-stock-over-other-positions-given-a-spatial-structure) has been clarified and can be reopened.

Comment: You think the question should be reopened, but doesn't deserve an upvote? -- I think it seems a bit weird to vote to reopen a question with no upvote, but 4 downvotes ... .

Comment: @Stefan, I'm sure the downvotes came before the editing.

Comment: Have voted to reopen

Comment: @Yemon, the question was deleted some weeks ago. I imagine it has to be undeleted before it can be reopened.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: now undeleted

Comment: @GerryMyerson Meanwhile the question has been autodeleted again since it is still closed and has non-positive score. To resurrect the question, it would take 3 undelete votes, 3 more reopen votes and either 5 upvotes (to reach score 1) or an answer, in order to permanently prevent it from being autodeleted again.

Answer (score 0):

[UNDELETED]

This question
[Order statistic of Markov chain sample path and related probabilities](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228385/order-statistic-of-markov-chain-sample-path-and-related-probabilities)

which was auto-deleted due to lack of activity or votes, seems reasonable to me. But I am not a probabilist; comments from those who are would be welcome

Comment: It's in danger of getting auto-deleted again, if it doesn't get some upvotes – isn't that right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think one upvote is sufficient, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

[[REOPENED](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/268150/revisions)]

[Graduate-level reference on temporal point processes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268150/graduate-level-reference-on-temporal-point-processes?noredirect=1#comment663033_268150) seems like a perfectly reasonable [reference-request](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/reference-request) / [textbook-recommendation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/textbook-recommendation).  The topic is research level but could be introduced in an advanced graduate text or monograph.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

I originally voted to close [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271588/local-property-of-split-exact-sequence/271596). I've since reconsidered, and I've voted to reopen.

Basically, there are easy counterexamples for infinitely generated modules, slightly more sophisticated counterexamples for finitely generated but not finitely presented modules, and a positive answer for finitely presented modules. In comments, knowledgeable people have made false claims, so I think it's probably close enough to "research level" to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

[UNDELETED and then REOPENED]

The question
[Checking concavity of a highly non linear function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275624/checking-concavity-of-a-highly-non-linear-function)

seems to have been closed over-hastily. Those with sufficient rep can see fedja's comments, and I am prepared to believe quite readily that if fedja thinks it is non-trivial, it is non-trivial.

I would like to nominate this for re-opening.

Comment: How does this work – can a deleted question be reopened without first being undeleted? or does reopening automatically accomplish undeleting?

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

[A game-theoretical question in a political economy model](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281512/a-game-theoretical-question-in-a-political-economy-model)
is a well-written math question coming from research in a field outside of mathematics.  It may well be easy but I think overall it would be worthwhile to reward the author with an answer.

Comment: You're right -- the question is vastly improved from its initial formulation.  I voted to reopen.

Comment: Looking at the [timeline](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/281512/timeline) I see that this question went through [the reopen review](https://mathoverflow.net/review/reopen/88254) with 3 votes to *leave closed*. However, it seems that some of the edits were made after the reviewers' votes. (Probably the OP is unaware that it is *the first edit* that pushes the question into the reopen review queue. Although I am not sure whether it made much difference in this specific case.)

Answer (score 0):

[[REOPENED](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/282441/revisions)]

The question [Why there exists a non-split sequence with the condition that $pdM=\infty$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282441/why-there-exists-a-non-split-sequence-with-the-condition-that-pd-m-infty) was originally posted with unexplained hypotheses and notation, and I voted to close and left a comment. The OP has edited the question and it now seems basically fine. I've voted to reopen

Answer (score 0):

[Undeleted]

Could I request that [Question 290941](https://mathoverflow.net/q/290941/), "Is the Normal centralizer problem in P?" be undeleted? It is a sensible question, and I spent some time finding a reference for the answer. It was then deleted by the poster - I have no idea why.

Comment: For the benefit of users who are below [10k reputation points](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/moderator-tools), at the moment some version of that question is still [visible in Google cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://mathoverflow.net/q/290941).
And it is also mentioned in the question that the same question was asked on Theoretical Computer Science site: [Is Normal centralizer problem in P?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/39798).

Answer (score 0):

[UNDELETED AND REOPENED]

[Can finite binary self-distributive algebras fit into small $n$-ary self-distributive algebras?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/289277/22277)

**Can finite binary self-distributive algebras fit into small n
-ary self-distributive algebras?**

This question was deleted because it got no upvotes. A possible reason that the question did not get any upvotes is that it necessarily requires $n$-ary fundamental operations for $n>2$ and mathematicians typically do not work with ternary or $n$-ary fundamental operations [See this question for possible explanations and for a discussion of ternary operations.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/49437/22277) Another possible reason it did not gain any upvotes is that the notion of $n$-ary self-distributivity has barely been studied.

Here are some reasons why the question and notions behind the question are reasonable.

1. The notion of $n$-ary self-distributivity generalizes the notion of an “inner endomorphism” to a more general context. I have encountered $n$-ary self-distributivity in my encounters with ternary and $n$-ary Laver tables (ternary Laver tables are really cool).
2. While the notion of $n$-ary self-distributivity may seem a bit difficult to investigate, the hull of an $n$-ary self-distributive algebra allows one to use binary self-distributivity to study $n$-ary self-distributivity. Since binary self-distributivity is easier to grapple with than $n$-ary self-distributivity, one should always take the hull of an $n$-ary self-distributive algebra.
3. This question is one of the more basic questions one can ask about the hull of $n$-ary self-distributive algebras and about the nature of $n$-ary self-distributivity.

Comment: Now, someone has cast an unexplained and unjustified downvote against this question. I have been getting many such unjustified downvotes for some time now.

Comment: Now that I think about it, a 50 point bounty would have probably prevented such a question from being deleted in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

[UN DELETED AND REOPENED]

[Is the variety of ternary self-distributive algebras generated by its finite members?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/289275/22277)

**Is the variety of ternary self-distributive algebras generated by its finite members?**

To convince you that this is a good question, let me explain a little about the mathematics behind this question.

Richard Laver has constructed a sequence $(A_{n})_{n\in\omega}$ of finite self-distributive algebras (which I now call the classical Laver tables), and he has shown under the existence of very large cardinals that the free self-distributive algebra on one generator embeds into $\varprojlim_{n\in\omega}A_{n}$. In particular, the free self-distributive algebra on one generator is contained in the variety generated by the classical Laver tables.

So I have extended the notion of the classical Laver table to a wide class of structures including the multigenic Laver tables. Furthermore, I have shown under strong large cardinal hypotheses that the free self-distributive algebra on countably many generators embeds into an inverse limit of multigenic Laver tables (the multigenic Laver tables are like the classical Laver tables but with multiple generators). In particular, the multigenic Laver tables generate the variety of all self-distributive algebras.

Now, the notion of self-distributivity can be generalized to $n$-ary self-distributivity and these generalized notions of self-distributivity give one an abstract notion of what it means for an algebraic structure to have “inner endomorphisms.” The notion of a Laver table can also be generalized to the notion of a ternary and $n$-ary Laver table. The only problem is that while the classical and multigenic Laver tables are always locally finite, the ternary Laver tables are in general not locally finite. The variety of ternary self-distributive algebras is probably generated by the ternary Laver tables, but since the ternary Laver tables are not locally finite, it is hard for me to predict whether the variety of self-distributive algebras is generated by its finite members.

Answer (score 0):

[DELETED, Undeleted]

[Reversible varieties](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321801/reversible-varieties)

In this question I asked about reversible varieties, and it seems like the question has been deleted unfairly. The question has 2 unexplained and unjustified downvotes and only 1 upvote, so it automatically got deleted. I do not believe that these downvotes have any legitimacy since I have recently been receiving many downvotes and all of these downvotes for the questions that I have asked are without any explanation.

In this question, I proposed the notion of a reversible variety since I noticed that several varieties including the varieties of groups, racks, quandles, and other varieties have a flavor of reversibility in the sense that the fundamental operations are simply projections of bijective functions which are composed of these fundamental operations. I think of the notion of a reversible variety as being a generalization of the notion of a group. I therefore wanted to know if this notion has been investigated before in the concept of universal algebra, and I also want to see more interesting examples of reversible varieties.

This question so far does not have much to do with reversible computation, and the motivation for this question did not arise from reversible computation.

Incidentally, this follow-up question ([Is this condition sufficient for a variety to be reversible?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321889/is-this-condition-sufficient-for-a-variety-to-be-reversible)) which is also about reversible varieties has not been downvoted nor upvoted (and hence not yet deleted).

Comment: People are misusing meta in order to cast more unjustified downvotes to questions related to the deleted questions.

Comment: Is there any reason why this post has a downvote?

Comment: The MO community has recently made it exceedingly clear that they do not want me on this site.

Comment: I see one downvote. ONE! A downvote doesn't mean someone doesn't want you here. I know you're not interested in my advice, but https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJUhlRoBL8M

Comment: Oh, and, for the 17th time, if you feel you're being targeted with downvotes, please, please flag for moderator attention. Complaining here is pointless, as only a moderator can do anything about such a situation.

Comment: Question has been undeleted BUT unless it sees some action (answers, upvotes) it will sooner or later be robo-deleted again.

Comment: I have been flagging these sorts of posts for unjustified downvotes. In my recent experience, such flags have been declined.

Answer (score 0):

[[REOPENED](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/335697/revisions)]

The closure of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335697/misspelling-my-name-on-my-mathematical-publications) seems rather rude to me, in particular in view of the strong gender bias on this site. -- Also I think neither its vote score nor that of its five upvoted answers supports the claim that it is considered off-topic on this site. Therefore I suggest to reopen that question.

Comment: Note that the vote scores have been inflated by the fact that the question became a HNQ, so they do not necessarily reflect opinions of regular participants of MO.

Comment: Also, it is off topic, as its connection to mathematics is by circumstance, not design. If it were happening in a different field, say biologists venturing into mathematics, I don't think it would stand at all as on topic for this forum. I am willing to consider it an exception to the rules and leave it for inclusion. Its popularity does not make it on topic. Gerhard "Will Not Vote To Delete" Paseman, 2019.07.11.

Comment: FWIW I have cast a 5th vote to reopen

Answer (score 0):

[No response from the OP, so I will leave this lie. I'm not that keen that I'm going to chase it up]

The question [How to sort differential equation list?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336478/how-to-sort-differential-equation-list) seems to me to be not uninteresting. The original asked about how to sort a list of DEs in Maple, but it's not really the Maple content that the asker is interested in, but rather if there is some reasonable ordering on (a class of) differential equations such that given a collection of them one could sort it into a list, so as to compare with other resources like OEIS.

It still very badly worded, but the above is what I think the OP wanted to ask.

Comment: I'd rather see OP rewrite the question so it's actually comprehensible. Perhaps by explaining it to someone who is fluent in Emglish, math, and whatever language is native for OP.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This is more of a preliminary notice. I was going to encourage the OP to explain it more clearly.

Comment: Given the terrible language, it’s not even clear to me if the question is really about *differential* equations, or if it’s just a mangled form of *different*.

Answer (score 0):

[UNDELETED]

I would like to add as undelete-request [*On variants of the abc conjecture in terms of Lehmer means*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350998/on-variants-of-the-abc-conjecture-in-terms-of-lehmer-means) that was automatically deleted yesterday. If possible, I think that it is an interesting question about the abc conjecture. Many thanks.

Comment: I note that you haven't enacted any of my suggestions for making the question more attractive to other users.

Comment: I don't know if you've read my comment adressed to you (in the Meta post now deleted), that I can not edit my question since it is deleted. When I thy to edit the post, this message is communicated "This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed."  Many thanks in any case @GerryMyerson and good weekend

Comment: @user142929 That seems some a bug which was also reported here: [“This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed” when editing own Roomba'd question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332201). (Some possible workarounds are mentioned there, but it would definitely be better if the bug was fixed.)

Comment: Mnay thanks @MartinSleziak

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment on https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4462/reasking-a-question-that-was-automatically-deleted-by-community-is-this-right-a (and why did you delete that question?).

Comment: You do not have to apologize about you missed the comment. I' ve deleted my Meta post since I want to solve my problem: which is about of a question that I consider interesting and important was automatically deleted @GerryMyerson . I don't know if ask a post for a discussion in Meta of these sites is useful, let's say that I've lost part of my hope in the discussions of the Meta of these sites, and that the first thing is solve my problem.

Comment: Now it's undeleted, you should be able to edit your post.

Comment: Many thanks/Muchas gracias I've edited it while it was deleted, I can't make more substantial improvements following the professor's advices (see previous linked Meta, my previous recently deleted post in Meta) in this post, similar that those that I edited while it was deleted, but my purpose is to moderate/modulate myself posts following the advices, in particular I will try show my effort and more motivation in next posts @YCor . Sure that my post is interesting and after this stumbling block we can solve it

Comment: If the question doesn't attract some upvotes and/or answers, presumably it will be auto-deleted again.

Comment: Many thanks for the information, someone upvote it, and I hope that some user do some attempt to solve it. My motivation is my feeling that can be an interesting post: I would not have insisted if the deleted post had been another of my posts (other unanswered post that maybe isn't interesting). Many thanks again to you and professors that vote undeleted the question @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 0):

Status [UNDELETED]  . (Thank you!)

I ask that [Counting multiples in short intervals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348571/counting-multiples-in-short-intervals) be recovered. I will provide an answer that is an enhancement of Lucia's comment as well as motivation for the question.  It is part of my exploration of a combinatorial approach in number theory. (GRP20200411)

Comment: "be recovered"?

Comment: If it were voted into deletion by members, I might say undeleted.  Instead, an algorithm determined it be deleted, and I want it recovered. Thank you for interest and help. Gerhard "Now To Take Some Steps" Paseman, 2020.04.11.

Comment: OK, well, it seems to be there now.

Answer (score 0):

[REOPENED]

The question
[$2$-norm of idempotent matrix](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409447/2-norm-of-idempotent-matrix)
was closed, but I didn't think the answer was obvious, although an answer has been provided via a link in a comment. I think that comment could be left as an answer, so I have voted to reopen.

It also seems to me that some people who voted to close, and some who left comments, interpreted $\Vert \cdot\Vert_2$ as meaning the Hilbert--Schmidt norm whereas I think it is meant to be the operator norm. (Considering diagonal $3\times 3$ matrices shows that the result is false for any Schatten p-norm with $p<\infty$.)

Answer (score 0):

[[REOPENED](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/457909/revisions)]

Reopening request for the question ["Potency set" for power set](https://mathoverflow.net/q/457909/37385)

An edit to explain that the question asks for a reference was included, and the tag reference was added.

Moreover, another edit explains that it is relevant that for historical reasons, "power set" is an English translation of the German "Potenzmenge", which is still in use in German mathematical literature.

Answer (score -1):

[REOPENED]

I request to reopen my question

[Different Metrics for Baire Space and their induced Topologies](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141421/different-metrics-for-baire-space-and-their-induced-topologies)

At first I had some flaws in the definition which I corrected by several edits and reedits, which made my post meandering. Now I totally rephrased the question and wrote it new. Also maybe I could delete the comment on my first definitions which are out of context now.

Answer (score -1):

[REOPENED]

A new user asked [an interesting question on Tychonoff spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142128/is-there-a-tychonoff-space-x-of-cardinality-not-of-the-form-2-alpha-such-th/142134#142134), and then proceeded to delete it after it was answered. But I don't see any reason for it to be deleted, so let's reopen it.

Comment: I undeleted since that was exploiting the system. Once your answer gains a few votes, the OP will no longer be able to unilaterally delete their question.

Comment: Thanks, François. I think probably it was not exploitation, but just lack of knowledge about what he or she was supposed to do.

Answer (score -1):

[REOPENED]

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147187/on-exactness-of-the-functors-m-mapsto-hatm-and-m-mapsto-hata-otimes) about completions was closed pretty quickly, presumably because people thought the answer was obvious or elementary.  They might be right, but if so, I'm failing to see the obvious.

I wonder whether some of the close votes might have resulted from a too-hasty reading that led people to think the OP was asking something like "Is the map $\hat{A}\otimes M\rightarrow \hat{M}$ always an isomorphism?"  If that were the question, I'd have voted to close it, but the actual question seems substantially more interesting.

Comment: As it turns out, the answer was in fact obvious and elementary, so I understand the close votes.  On the other hand, the posted answer goes beyond the obvious and elementary, and I learned something from it.  So I'm glad this got re-opened, even if it was for the wrong reason.

Answer (score -1):

[REOPENED]

I'd like to see [Subsets of Real Numbers (Edited & Revised Version)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150459/subsets-of-real-numbers-edited-revised-version) reopened. The original question was a bit unclear, I read "between the lines" and wrote an answer; the question was closed and feedback was given in the comments.

The question was edited to its current shape, which is a good question (and definitely at research level).

I mean, this is how the system should work: vague question getting closed; edited to a clear question; reopened.

Comment: As Stefan Kohl mentioned in the comments, while the new question is reasonable, it is completely different from the original question. This is *not* how the system should work.

Comment: Emil, I agree that it is *somewhat* different. But it is not *very* different from how I originally interpreted the question.

Answer (score -1):

[REOPENED]

(**Edit:** Since no one responded to the question of whether the closure reason is still valid, I took it upon myself to ask Joel David Hamkins, who discerns a clear and interesting interpretation and has expressed interest in answering, provided that the question remains open long enough. Therefore I cast a fourth vote to reopen.)

The post [Can there be ordinals larger than those contained in Ord, and if so, can they be used to extend the constructible universe $L$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/189000/can-there-be-ordinals-larger-than-those-contained-in-ord-and-if-so-can-they-be) is currently on hold as "unclear what you're asking", but now that the question has been substantially edited, one user has flagged that this reason for on-hold no longer applies. If it is still unclear, then perhaps someone can say why, else I request a reopening.

Comment: What I want to know is, why, when you ask people who wish to close a question to state their concerns, they don't? In the case of Noah S (as you can see from our conversation in the Comments), I was willing to address his concerns and would have been willing to address theirs as well.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Yes, that would be nice. Three of the closers have professional interests in this area and could probably articulate such concerns, if they still apply (I think Noah S does too, but he was not one of the closers). Some people vote to close because they see no reason to disagree with other closers, as expressed here: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1954/why-this-is-off-topic#comment8933_1954 -- based on that stance, I wouldn't expect them to state their concerns.

Answer (score -1):

[REOPENED]

[Combinatorial puzzles involving half-integers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191537/combinatorial-puzzle-involving-half-integers)

I believe it was put on-hold because of my inadequate definition of what I previously termed "guide lines". I fixed this. The only potential ambiguity left is my definition of "cells".

Moreover, the question garnered two upvotes in a very short period of time, so I feel reopening it is fair.

Comment: The statement of the question does seem clear now; this means the "unclear what you're asking" no longer applies. The consideration then becomes whether it is considered on-topic for MO.

Comment: So, Todd, do we reopen and then discuss whether it's on-topic? or do we decide whether it's on-topic, and, if it is, then reopen?

Comment: I think we only reopen it if we decide that it is on-topic.

Comment: @GerryMyerson What Andy said. Of course, people can decide on their own without there being a particular discussion.

Answer (score -1):

The question

[Mathematics of Computer science and AI](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195885/mathematics-of-computer-science-and-ai)

has recently been edited by someone after the OP in an effort to improve it, or make it more focused. I am ambivalent as to whether it should be reopened but I thought it deserved explicit mention/discussion on meta.MO

Answer (score -2):

I'd like to know why my question [Looking for a conference about renormalization group methods](https://mathoverflow.net/q/148600/30967) has been closed.

As I said in the comments, there are other similar question such as the one that asking about [Conferences about homotopy theory](https://mathoverflow.net/q/16360/30967), one looking for [Mathematical conferences](https://mathoverflow.net/q/6852/30967) in general, were rather positively received and allowed to attract nice answers.

Is there anything I can do to get it reopend? Maybe it should be CW?

Comment: You are comparing to questions that were asked more than 3 years ago. The sort of soft questions people like has changed.

Comment: Another issue here is that this question is much narrower than the ones you listed, which were likely to be of interest to large groups of mathematicians.

Answer (score -2):

[REOPENED]

Mathematical explenation for why warm water freezes faster than cold water.
[Mathematical study of Mpemba effect?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153669/mathematical-study-of-mpemba-effect) is a good question in applied mathematics and I propose to open it.

Answer (score -2):

[REOPENED]

[This question about Zariski topology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163815/is-it-meaningful-to-work-on-convergencies-integration-etc-on-the-zariski-topo) is interesting, relevant but unclear, and it attracted two excellent answers. The question is ambigious and unclear because the situation is genuinly unclear to the OP  who is  <del>a professional mathematician</del>  trying to explore a topic. It is unclear in a way where it is possible to understand what the author is thinking, and give useful answers for him and for others.

Comment: Why do you expect the OP to be a professional mathematician? Also, he has been asked a quite specific question in the comments which might clarify what he means. Without an answer to that question I do not feel there is any good reason to reopen the question.

Comment: In an effort to understand how people use this thread, and think it should be used, with an eye towards improving our procedures, I would like to know if you: a. did not know of  http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1650/why-was-this-question-closed or b. did know of it but still posted here.

Comment: Hi Quid, My post follows Frank Thorne's question (using similar wordings) and Todd's remark that mentioned this thread. I agree with Todd that the question is unclear (and not merely "slightly ambigious") but I think that the question reflects an issue which can be unclear to researchers in mathematics, and is thus research-level and should be welcome on MO. Of course, an endorsement to open not coming from the OP himself carries additional weight and I also want to endorse a policy of allowing umbigious questions of the kind a working mathematician occasionally have.

Comment: Gil, I think such a policy is contrary to the goals of MathOverflow.  I think you should endorse a policy of encouraging a questioner to participate in improving their question.  This policy might mean a 48-hour hold before a "soft-" close of a question, but to have a new user ask something that needs improvement and does not respond to requests for that improvement is a situation that does not bode well for the forum.  Better to make a temporary edit on the new person's behalf, or close the question.  Gerhard "Or Start A New Question" Paseman, 2014.04.21

Comment: Right Gerhard, I certainly demand that the OP will make all possible effort to make his question clear before posing a vague question. But sometimes we encounter in our research/study  questions which are (or seem to be) inherently vague.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! To avoid all risk of misunderstanding, let me stress again that my question was not meant as indirect criticism of you posting here. As the thread exists, it is a reasonable usage of it.

Comment: Gil, it seems we are in general agreement.  When (the community of) MathOverflow is robust enough to handle such questions, then a more lenient policy can be adopted.  I think the current success is due to the fact that almost all of the unclosed questions are focused, ask for specific things, and require little or no discussion as to meaning (after the formulation has stabilized).  I think overestimating the robustness of the community is a real danger: supplementing vague questions with answerable portions may be a solution.  Gerhard "Wants Success Without A Doubt" Paseman, 2014.04.21

Comment: I agree with Tobias. Referring to the OP as a "professional mathematician" is unwarranted and gilds the lily. The form of the question leaves little doubt that the OP is a student ("recently studied algebra", etc.), and OP *still* hasn't bothered to clarify the question, and I still disagree with "it is unclear in a way where it is possible to understand what the author is thinking" -- one can only *guess* what he/she is thinking. Why this question is being given a pass is simply beyond me.

Comment: My confusion guys, I thought that Frank Thorne is the OP. Sorry!

Comment: I agree with Todd Trimble on this.  When a question is closed as unclear, and this one is admittedly so, then it makes sense to edit and clarify it before reopening (which may well be warranted here).  I am a little surprised that no one has bothered to edit this question, and yet it has been reopened.

Comment: Silly mistake! Sorry again, but at least I learned the expression "gilds the lily. :)

Answer (score -2):

[DELETED by OP]

[Please re-open this.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/306968/14414) If you find it worth, or least please comment if you think its not worth it, with reason. I have since edited the question and I believe the current version is more clear.

Answer (score -3):

**Redeleted**

Requesting to undelete my [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321671/appropriate-logic-for-modeling-uncertainty-in-logic). I carefully worked through the comments in order to rephrase the question so it would be more understandable what I'm asking for, only to see that it has been deleted within hours (instead of days as stated in the help center), preventing effective research.

---

update (27/1/2019): the question has now been undeleted

Answer (score -3):

Only two more votes needed to reopen [Funny names of mathematical objects?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389482/funny-names-of-mathematical-objects)

There is valid comment that very similar question exists on MSE, but we believe that this reasoning will close a lot of other stuff.

Answer (score -3):

I request for reopen the question with identificartor **423548** and title [*Soft question around the equivalent forms of Riemann hypothesis: an overview of the role of these equivalent forms*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423548/soft-question-around-the-equivalent-forms-of-riemann-hypothesis-an-overview-of), and this post is adressed to the readers (the recipient isn't, in exclusive, the professor who edited this thread post(s) in Meta).

I have a critic. The clousure of my question seems unfair, and now it's a challenge, for all us, to reopen it. If you've upvoted to close it, please be a leader and help me to reopen the question again.

With reverence and honors for the professors who stated an equivalent form to the Riemann hypothesis, I ask about the freedom to discuss the (mathematical) meaning of such big collection of equivalent forms. Don't wait, please, the next new dozen of equivalent forms and help now to improve the understanding about what's the Riemann hypothesis.

We must to know... don't put in risk the reputation of your profession in the way that any student could to ask, in a hall, the reason why is closed my question in MathOverflow.

'We must to know', said a mathematician. And at this date, in which we've forgotten the naive days, I'm sure of these words, that we can do it. Because we, mathematicians, need just an Attic night to rescue our civilizations. So, this can be a starting point of a coming hope memories, and a chance for all us.

Comment: Why the Riemann hypothesis and not the free group factor problem? Also, it is consistent for people to believe that the RH is important while believing that the question you posted on MO is not going to help. (I did not vote to close your question, and I did not downvote it)

Comment: "Because we, mathematicians, need just an attic night to rescue our civilizations." I love this. I don't have the foggiest idea what it means, but I love it.

Comment: I've upvoted both responses, yours professor @YemonChoi and the response of the other professor. I once time was a student, and we think in this way, that a professor as you or the professor in previous comment aren't a stamp collectors of hundred of equivalent forms of a core problem in mathematics, and isn't my view. Because aren't my equivalent forms, aren't my words 'we must to know', isn't my profession, I'm just an amateur mathematician. You can to ask to your colleagues (professors that you know) about the importance of Riemann hypothesis in modern mathematics. Many thanks for boths.

Comment: Wikipedia has the article *Aulus Gellius* that refers his work *Attic Nights*. Many thanks for your attention in my posts @GerryMyerson . And yes, we can to rescue our civilization and culture as mathematicians, because even in the worse conditions only are required a few men and women to burn a fire with flames of hope (this fire as metaphor of critical thinking and constructive feedback in mathematics or physics).

Comment: Please I add also as reference, if I interpret well the words of authors, the last paragraph in page 58 and the (first) paragraph in page 59, both of Chapter 17 from their book Barry Mazur and William Stein, *Prime Numbers and the Riemann Hypothesis*, Cambridge University Press (2016). For instance you can to read (in page 59) that the authors (if I refer well) coined a denomination for this "conjecture" (I mean the Riemann hypothesis).

Comment: Please if some user can to help upvoting this post that he/she does it. I appreciate it, many thanks.

Answer (score -4):

[[REOPENED, RECLOSED, REOPENED](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/152352/revisions)]

The question [Is Euclid dead?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/152352/6085) has gone through a couple of rounds of closing and reopening. It is currently closed (and I have voted to reopen).

I think that the responses make the question worthwhile, independently of any perceived agendas behind it (see [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1301/6085) for that). And I believe we had agreed that in cases of questions that clearly generate good responses (the quality of which may not have yet peaked), the default if there are closing/reopen "wars" was to keep the question open. Regardless, I believe this particular question deserves to stay active.

(**N.B.** I have made a substantial edit to the question -- Todd Trimble).

Comment: Andres, can you remind me where this agreement was reached? Relevant might be the Stone Soup thread, particularly this answer http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/1047/2926, but I'm skeptical that 'agreement' was reached.

Comment: (I may misremember. Probably buried somewhere on tea. I'll post a link if I manage to find it...)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have just now substantially edited the question to remove what I thought were the most objectionable aspects (as mentioned by Joël for instance).

Comment: Regarding open-close wars, I did see a comment by François at http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1579/2/is-rigour-just-a-ritual-that-most-mathematicians-wish-to-get-rid-of-if-they-could/ which might be pertinent.

Comment: Ah, that may be it.

Comment: I think we also had agreement that controversial questions especially if they already have their proper meta thread are discussed there first before posting in this thread. (That meta got deleted at some poin but from the timestamps it seems it had returned already when you posted this). In addition "a couple of rounds of closing and reopening" seems like a significant exageration. When you wrote that it was only reclosed once (as is now). At best this are 1 and 1/2 rounds so in no sense "a couple"

Comment: I agree that this thread should only be used for those questions that are not controversial, and where their reason for not having been reopened is more likely due to people not having noticed something (either because several people misread the question, or because the question has been edited).

Comment: Couldn't you at least just have deleted it now? The abuse here starts to get annoying.

Comment: Well, I don't see it as abuse, but I think quite a few of us *are* getting tired of this troubled question. I would like to register some disagreement with a claim that the answers have made the question worthwhile: I have felt an obligation to delete at least five of them, and some that have remained emit more heat than light. My personal opinion is that the question should remain closed: it has proven to be more trouble than it's worth (but perhaps I am too close to this to be fully impartial, and I am reticent about being the one to bring down the hammer, after all my activity).

Comment: @ToddTrimble 'abuse' was perhaps a bit a strong word. But, 1st, it is (counterfactually, IMO) claimed that due to some agreement not even recallable (upon being asked) the q has to be reopened, thereby implying that those (re)closing it did not follow 'agreement'. 2nd, posting here while a q has an active meta thread is rather not to be done. This was pointed out directly by 2 users (Tobias Kildetoft and me), but completely ignored, even editing twice at least the 2nd one being avoidable, except if one still just wants it to get it opened without proper disc. about the merits.

Comment: @quid Having two posts on such closely related topics *is* a little awkward, but a justification for 'ignoring' the other thread is that Stefan's question was about the *general* propriety of using MO to wage a campaign, slightly different to what is being asked here (which is directly about the specific MO question; we've been using this space recently for reopen requests). I think Andres is within rights to uphold the distinction (which has been muddied a little). Also, there have been various vague 'guidelines' proposed and gropings for 'agreement' for open-close tugs of war, as in (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) the Stone Soup thread -- another awkward situation where exactly what was said or semi-agreed on by some parties becomes hard to recall. (I think those semi-agreed-on situations really have to be watched closely; they make *me* feel uncomfortable.)

Comment: @ToddTrimble: The 'ignoring' did not refer to ignoring the other thread but the related remarks here. I know various things got discussed; the question is what precisely should apply. The post is in this and other ways (eg, a couple of rounds) a bit generous regarding facts. This is especially problematic as as documented not everybody takes the time to get familiar themselves with a thread before voting open/close on it. I think a bit more care is to be expected from a highrep user when suggesting a reopening.

Answer (score -4):

[DELETED]

I don't understand why the question

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191499/can-the-divisibility-by-7-test-be-extended-to-preserve-the-remainder

has attracted such heavy downvoting and was closed so quickly. I have not thought deeply about the question, but a look at the OP's previous questions and his profile suggests this is not some idle high-school question.

Comment: I find the closure understandable: given the volume of off-topic questions, and given the somewhat recreational tone (which makes it seem not too close to modern research concerns), it's not surprising that people would vote to close without much thought. I'm not convinced yet it would be good for MO, but I haven't thought deeply about it either.

Comment: Looking at the question, I think it was reasonable to close it.  The test of divisibility is to replace $10a+b$ by $a-2b$.  The complaint was that $a-2b$ is not the same as $10a+b \pmod 7$.  Well then $3$ times $a-2b$  leaves the same remainder.  I didn't downvote this, or vote to close, but I also can't see voting to reopen either.

Answer (score -4):

[Deleted]

[Is there any application of Mochizuki's IUT for mathematical physics?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/264999/is-there-any-application-of-mochizukis-iut-for-mathematical-physics)

This has been closed as being "primarily opinion-based" --- if there is a possible application I would actually be very interested to learn about it.

Comment: What is good about a question that asks whether a theory that has not been widely understood/accepted has applications to problems that are not specified.  And this is the most polite way in which I can describe that and other Mochizuki questions!

Answer (score -5):

[DELETED]

My question is on hold and seems fairly likely to be on the way to be closed. I request a re-opening:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275786/counterexample-required-standard-notations

I have edited my original post to post my question in a formatted way now. As I have stated a few times in that thread, if someone feels that there are issues or doubts with regards to clarity of the question, then I would try to address that.

Comment: The question can be deleted as I have figured the answer to my question as to why a refutation example would exist (for the criterion in question).

Comment: I think I didn't read original post carefully enough before editing. As I have understood now reading it more carefully, it seems that it is only required to mention the [re-opening] for a question at the start, but not necessarily a [deletion]. But I guess it doesn't matter much anyway.

Answer (score -5):

[Deleted]

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283185/the-distinction-between-countable-and-uncountable-infinity-within-a-constructivi

The fact that this question admits the kind of commentary that has been posted by Thomas Benjamin shows that it has content suitable for mathoverflow.

Answer (score -8):

Thank you for your earlier support, Professor Myerson. I would like to request https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135605/how-to-discover-counterexamples-and-required-objects to be reopened. On the claim that it is "too broad," I would like to propound the suggestion by Dr Asghari in the comments:

> to address Hennry concern I suggest to change the question to CW and let a more experienced MO user revise the question in an appropriate way for MO...

In addition, I do not understand why my question is considered "too broad" in comparison with [Mathematical habits of thought and action which would be of use to non-mathematicians](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74707/mathematical-habits-of-thought-and-action-which-would-be-of-use-to-non-mathemati). It would seem that habits can be myriad as well as highly subjective, though they constitute answers to that Question. Notwithstanding the potentially wide ambit to [Mathematical habits of thought and action which would be of use to non-mathematicians](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74707/mathematical-habits-of-thought-and-action-which-would-be-of-use-to-non-mathemati), it remains open and its multifarious answers prove very helpful and insightful.

Comment: The "instructional counterexamples" question was posted in March 2010. MO has changed since then, and it is generally accepted that "but question x from 2010 is still open" is not a sufficient argument for keeping question x' from 2013 open.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thank you for your information. I have been trying to browse through past, more recent Soft Questions to grasp my question's fitness and may have found one that I hope can support my question. I have edited my request above.

Comment: You really have to make a case for your question on its own merits. I think you have to rewrite it in line with the comments on it to give it a chance of being (re-)re-opened. By the way, the "habits" question was somewhat controversial, and went through a close-reopen cycle.

Comment: To strength what @GerryMyerson said "somewhat controversial" is quite an understatement of my opinion on this other question. And, Le Pressentiment in my opinion you use this thread in a way it it is not intended. You anyway have a meta-question on your question, *and* there is already an entry in this thread for you question, *and now you edit* your additional entry. This is a bit too much, in my opinion.

Comment: @quid: I have made another post but in the Meta-question following your request. I referenced the question on Habits because the sheer number of users who have upvoted, favourited, and its status as open seem to imply its relevance and significance. Please let me know if you have other suggestions.

Comment: Also, I would be grateful for explanations from those who downvoted.

Comment: The original link is broken, due to "moderation."  Should this answer now be deleted?

Comment: @Carl: the question was deleted (by users) some time ago (I slightly disagree with the deletion for abstarct reasons, and there are two votes to undelete) before the latest edit to this answer. There thus seems no reason that now this answer should be deleted. (Though I wished this entire episode came to an end soon.) // To OP: if you mean the downvotes to this meta-answer, I think it is clear enough from what I wrote why one might downvote this (which I actually did). But also one can consider a downvote simply as vote against reopening.

Comment: @quid and OP: Sorry.  I guess the point is that ordinary users cannot see the original question after deletion and so cannot participate in discussion.  But as you say, this is probably for the best.

Answer (score -8):

[On meta: Ethical standards of the field of mathematics](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4194/ethical-standards-of-the-field-of-mathematics?noredirect=1#comment19914_4194) was closed and currently is at score +1/-7. I suppose the eccentric genius Perelman knows better than 5 users voting to close.

Comment: The eccentric genius Perelman knows better than to post questions to meta.mathoverflow that are clearly off-topic there.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It would be fun if Perelman is reading these threads :)

Comment: @GerryMyerson On second thought according to wikipedia Perelman quitted mathematics, so he wouldn't have posted for entirely different reasons.

Answer (score -11):

I had recently posted [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/428697/159957) which got 3 dvs plus a delete vote shortly after posting. I was quite upset by this because I was fairly confident with my answer as I actually read a considerable chunk of both of Needhams book.

If there is a mistake in my judgement, could it be that the mistake is pointed out instead of giving a barrage of dvs? Thanks.

Here is a picture of the post:

[image]

One person commented how it is that I am identifying asymptotics is the ultimate equality. It simply is the same thing. I believe Needham himself invented the equality for the book as I have gone through many books and have yet to find a similar concept being used to describe the issue.

Needham himself states in this book that the concept is more or less "proof beyond reasonable doubt" in the common sense than a proof in a rigorous mathematical sense

[image]

Further to verify my claims, Needham himself mentions that the ultimate equality is an equivalence relation:
[image]

[image]

If an exact definition of this concept is sought, I doubt that any possible person can give an authoritative answer to it. As only Needham would know as this concept with the name that Needham used is not shown in any standard DG books.

---

## Edit:

I have included this section in hopes of showing how my answer solves the question.

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows that the answer was deleted by a moderator. That means it cannot be undeleted by regular users: [Which actions by moderators cannot be reversed by community?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27189) (OTOH maybe one of the moderators might respond here.)

Comment: Fingers crossed I guess. @MartinSleziak

Comment: You didn’t just get a lot of downvotes, you also got a lot of feedback in the comments that  you turn a deaf ear to. Basically, there was no “mistake” in what you wrote, but it **did not answer the question**. The question is not what Needham means by *ultimate equality*; that much is clear, and already stated in the question. The question is what Needham means by *ultimately vanishing*, which you did not answer. (As pointed out in comments under the question, it does not make much sense to interpret it as “ultimately equal to $0$”.)

Comment: I think the issue many, including me, had was that your post explained "ultimately equal", which the questioner said they understood—not "ultimately vanishing", which was the subject of the question.  Now that you have added the addendum, one can point out that the questioner considers and rejects "ultimately equal to $0$" because, in the quotient-based definition, either every quantity is ultimately equal to $0$, or the quotient is ill formed (depending on which quantity goes in the denominator).  See the post body and [@GeraldEdgar's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comment/1102369).

Comment: I [misspoke](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/27606) twice.  My link to @GeraldEdgar's comment had a typo; it should have been https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1102369. I should also have said that either *nothing* (not everything) was ultimately equal to $0$ (according to the definition $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac0{B(\epsilon)} = 1$) or that the question was meaningless (according to the definition $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{A(\epsilon)}0 = 1$).