# Should this question remain closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The OP of [How to project a vector onto a very large, non-orthogonal subspace](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145688/how-to-project-a-vector-onto-a-very-large-non-orthogonal-subspace#question) has written to complain that the question was closed unfairly. The question is too far from my area of expertise to be confident the question is appropriate for MO, but it's certainly not clear to me that it isn't. I'm hoping some people who are in the know can weigh in here.

My own leanings are towards reopening, because the question seems to lie in an area that could stand greater representation at MO. But I'd defer to more expert opinion.

**Update:** The question has now been reopened.

Comment: One thing I thought might be improved in the question is the tagging. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The question could use more background. Presumably this is a real matrix filled with floating point numbers... Maybe it's better suited for [SciComp](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Yeah, could be. If it doesn't belong here, then it'd be very nice to suggest a better place for it.

Comment: More background would be helpful.  This looks to me (also not an expert, but probably less distant than Todd) like a serious question in numerical analysis.  The OP might be more likely to get a good answer on another site, but that's not exactly the same as being off-topic.

Comment: I am also not an expert in numerical linear algebra, but this looks like a serious question to me.  Perhaps those voting to close would be willing to say why this does not seem to be at an appropriate level for MO.

Comment: I voted to reopen. I'm not an expert on numerical linear algebra, but I don't think all of those who voted to close are, either.

Comment: For general information: the question got reopened.

Comment: This should have been posted, preferably by the OP, here: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/223/requests-for-reopen-votes

Comment: Thank you, @AsafKaragila. Sorry to have forgotten that.