# Why was "Is it meaningful to work on convergencies, integration, etc. on the Zariski topology?" closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

This post is about the question [Is it meaningful to work on convergencies, integration, etc. on the Zariski topology?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163815/) It is an interesting, relevant question which attracted two excellent answers. The question is slightly ambiguous, but in a way where it is easy to understand what the author is thinking, and the answers do an excellent job of addressing this ambiguity.

Added later: the question got reopened.

Comment: I am not at all enthusiastic about this question, and I think it was right to close it as being unclear (to me it *is* unclear). To me the answers don't exactly clarify the question; they are somewhat artful ways of talking about things that could be of interest to the OP, much in the way that a kind and skilled professor might address a confused or ineptly formulated question, making the best of a situation. (Incidentally, we have this thread for reopen requests: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/223/requests-for-reopen-votes.)

Comment: To me this question resembles the kind of discussions that I enjoyed as a grad student, both as asker and answerer, with other grad students in different specialties. Personally, when I am unsure how to best formulate a question, I especially appreciate an opportunity to ask it. If this type of question is unwelcome on MO, I would personally regard this as a loss, although I gather that my opinion is in the minority.

Comment: Well, the community should continue to have discussions about MO norms, and there are not a few who think the prevailing norms are too strict. My comment should be interpreted less as coming from an MO "cop" and more just a personal statement that I indeed found the question unclear; particularly that I don't get what OP meant by <<the Zariski topology is meaningful as being a "topology", rather than being a set which sufficies the axioms of being a topology. Is there a understandable example which views the Zariski topology as a "topology">> Did OP obliquely mean a Grothendieck topology??

Comment: I took "topology" (in quotes) to mean the sort of thing that one sees in elementary topology --- convergence, continuity, connectedness, and the like.  The answers made it clear that such things are not to be expected from the Zariski topology, which I think answers that part of the question (if I understood it correctly).

Comment: @AndreasBlass But he says '*a* "topology"' (my emphasis), not "topology" as a kind of collective noun. Anyway, I asked what was meant at MO main, and maybe OP will pop by to clear it up.

Comment: When I've read the question it immediately translated in my mind as "Topology is for talking about converging sequences: what the heck is the Zariski topology about?". Probably I got a bit carried away in my willingness to reply that there's more to geometry than converging sequences. That said I think that the question may use a clarification

Comment: Technically, this question is not "closed", it is merely "on hold".  This means it can be re-opened provided it is re-worded to make it acceptable.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I think you make a good point, but still I cannot help but point out that even if it were technically closed it could also be re-opened.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways of interpreting your question.  Literally, you seem to be asking for an explanation from those who voted to close the question.  I was one of them, and the question was genuinely unclear to me.  When I voted, I don't think there were any answers; but I am not sure if the answers (nice as they are) would have changed how I felt about the question.

But probably the spirit of your question is to ask for it to be reopened.  This is certainly reasonable, but I don't feel persuaded to cast a vote to reopen.  I think the question could be improved by someone (e.g. OP or you or ...) who feels they understand the spirit of it and is willing to edit it.

Finally, I posted this comment on main: there is a closely related question on MSE which I think is posed more clearly, and has a very nice answer by Matt E(merton).  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53852/is-there-a-way-of-working-with-the-zariski-topology-in-terms-of-convergence-limi/53912#53912

Comment: Please note that I was advocating on behalf of someone else's question -- I do agree that the question left room for improvement. Also, I agree that the question was very nicely posed and answered in the MSE link you mentioned!

Comment: @FrankThorne: I appreciate your point, which as I mentioned above is eminently reasonable.