# Why this is off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

I posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998307/campbell-baker-hausdorff-formula-for-log-expxy-expx-y) on MSE for two months and received no helpful answer. So I tried the same question on MO. I got 4 off-topic votes and so the question got migrated back to MSE. I'd like to mention that I actually got some upvotes before others downvoted it. So I'm wondering **What on earth is an off-topic on MO?** This is vaguely defined in MO's help center, as I quote:

> (on-topic) to ask and answer research level math questions, the sorts of questions you come across when you're writing or reading articles or graduate level books.

Although I did not ask a particular question from graduate level books, I certainly have already resorted to several before I asked the question--I didn't find a satisfying answer. Otherwise, why would I ask the question in the first place?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this question for MO, although I haven't thought hard about it. Perhaps one or more of the closers could explain.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Thank you for your support.

Comment: @StefanKohl Thanks for speaking up. My own feeling is that one should only vote to close based on one's personal belief about the question, independently of others (not seeing a reason to disagree being not the same as agreeing).

Comment: @StefanKohl Thanks for your honesty. If your viewpoint stands for most people here on MO, I am really disappointed.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: My impression is that only a pretty low percentage of the questions which get closed on MO are closed in error (it takes five votes to close a question, and anybody may post a comment pointing out that the question is suitable for MO, and be it only "why the close votes?") -- and if a question is closed, it may still be reopened. I think if people would cast close votes only when they are *absolutely sure* that there is nothing good in a question, it would probably be notably more difficult to keep the site on-topic.

Comment: I didn't vote on that question. FWIW, I used to follow roughly the same practice as @StefanKohl, but for about a year now (if not longer) I've followed the practice described in Todd's comment.

Comment: @StefanKohl "My impression is that only a pretty low percentage of the questions which get closed on MO are closed in error" -- I think I agree with that. "I think if people would cast close votes only when they are absolutely sure that there is nothing good in a question, it would probably be notably more difficult to keep the site on-topic." -- I think I (somewhat) disagree with that. But perhaps it would be best if we didn't pursue these generalities here and now, but simply focus on the question at hand, whether it was right to close this particular question.

Comment: The point is not to be absolutely sure, but to use your own judgement. If people are copying the opinion of other close voters, it effectively lowers the threshold from five votes to one.

Comment: I voted to close because I thought MSE is the right forum for the question, and it already exists there.  I commented on that thread but I've been distracted by other things the last few days so I haven't returned to it.

Comment: @RyanBudney I had discussed with you about it and I have removed the post from MSE under your suggestion. And you removed your comments too after that. So I was under the (obviously wrong) impression that the issue you held is solved. At least you should let people know the whole story, not to create misunderstanding again.

Comment: Could you give me a link to your deleted thread?  I'm confused as to what happened.  I don't remember what you're talking about but the past few weeks have been hectic for me so maybe I've just forgotten.  When I look at my history at MSE I can't find that old thread.  The address might be in one of my browser histories, but that might take some time to find.

Comment: @RyanBudney Sorry, I don't know how to find it. Once it is deleted, it cannot be found in my activity history.

Comment: Well, the question was sitting at MSE unanswered for two months and the migrated version is just sitting there now. Meanwhile I haven't heard any compelling reason for why the question is *wrong* for MO. (Troy should have said when he first posted at MO that it was already at MSE but was unanswered for a long time; crossposting is especially frowned upon when it goes unmentioned.) Is there some easy solution to the problem that makes it somehow inappropriate for MO? At this point I have my doubts, and think that Troy might try asking at MO again, pointing to this meta thread.

Comment: However, this last suggestion is for now made with my moderator's cap off. I would still very much like to hear from others if this question is considered not on-topic for MO.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Thank you for your kindness and support. I will improve my question and try again later (I will try my mathematician collaborator first...getting help from here is so difficult...).

Comment: Ultimately it's a pretty basic linear-algebra question in disguise.  I suspect the main reason why it does not have a response is that it isn't easy to get enthusiastic about non-commutative power series manipulations.

Comment: @RyanBudney I use the lie-gp lie-alg tag for a reason. The question is related to certain Lie triple systems $\mathfrak m$ in $\mathfrak{gl}_{\mathbb R}(n)$ where $[\mathfrak m,\mathfrak m]\cap\mathfrak m=0$. The product of exponentials I showed in my post are meant to generate some symmetric spaces. I didn't say it because I suspect there are ways to do it in general. As you said, I find it difficult to manipulate power series using Dynkin formula, this is why I turn to MO for professional suggestions. Thank you for letting me know it is "pretty basic linear-algebra".

Comment: @RyanBudney I'm sorry, but I really fail to see how your last comment is constructive. If it's "pretty basic", then perhaps you could show Troy Woo the light at MSE, perhaps with a few well-chosen hints? On the other hand, just because you yourself can't muster enthusiasm for it doesn't strike me as a good reason for closure at MO. I have to say that I'm a little skeptical that the problem is as easy as you seem to be implying here, but if you can't be bothered to explain, is there some good reason why someone else at MO shouldn't take a crack at it?

Comment: The question probably attracted downvotes because you didn't elaborate your thinking on the question.

Comment: @user170039 Thanks for your suggestion. I will elaborate more. The reason that I didn't is that I thought it might have a general solution, which does not necessarily have anything to do with LTS or the nice property about canonical embedding.

Comment: You normally get much more positive feedback when you explain why you are interested in the question, what you have tried, what are the obstacles, etc. as if you are explaining it to a colleague. MOers are typically more sympathetic to questions when authors demonstrate their own effort to find a solution themselves.