# OpenScience Q&A just went live

Tags: discussion

Perhaps you are aware of the fact that there was an Open Science private beta at StackExchange that did not quite manage to develop enough traction so it was closed down recently. [Some people want to start a second attempt there, some prefer a Discourse forum](https://gist.github.com/sckott/bb0df66b2967602a26fa) but Daniel Mietchen and I decided to go independent. So with a lot of help from the PhysicsOverflow admins (who also encouraged me to make this announcement here), I imported SE's XML dump into a fresh Question2Answer instance. And here it is:

https://openscience.ub.uni-bielefeld.de

If you had an account on the closed Open Science SE beta site, please reclaim it now (I am not allowed to post more than 2 URLs, so please click the current top question). Otherwise, feel free to register a new account if you are interested in Open Science, reproducibility and all that stuff. In any case, please indicate if you would be willing to join the admin or mods team. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I'll want to re-join, but this is really helpful. You might want to post this announcement elsewhere, to attract more of the folks who originally participated in the private beta.

Comment: The meta of the [Open Data](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/) community as a related site comes to mind as a place to post the announcement too and maybe also [Academia](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The "mods" team? Is that Q&A not community moderated?

Comment: @Turion It looks like it just got started on a new platform, so there's no team yet.

Comment: @HDE, yes, but I had assume that the active users earn moderator privileges by contributing to the site.

Comment: @Turion Ah, I thought you meant the equivalents of diamond moderators, which I thought Christian was referring to.

Comment: It'd make for a good post on [meta.physics.SE] too - or perhaps a community ad. We already have several linking to other Q&A sites of interest to the science community.

Comment: @Turion, thanks for joining Open Science Q&A! In the meantime, you will have noticed that the site is not moderated. Moderators are simply people with extra permissions. Open Science Q&A currently has 2 moderators, 2 admins, and 1 "super-admin" (me). This is a good start, but we still need more (wo)manpower, in all roles.

Comment: Sorry if I get the terminology wrong – I am not a frequent user of SE sites. I am not sure what “community moderated” entails. At the moment, anything goes. I also have no clue what diamond moderators are. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @ChristianPietsch, community moderated in the sense of SE means that any user achieves different moderating privileges by earning reputation. That way, the most active users with the most well-liked questions and answers become moderators.

Comment: The Q2A software as such does not have a convenient review system as the StackExchange software. So on PO, we use specific community moderation threads similar to the [Request for Reopen Votes](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/223/30967) on MO to community close, reopen, delete, and undelete posts. Maybe this might be the easiest and fastest way to install community moderation (with an appropriate rep threshold) for Open Science too if wished so?