# I fixed my question. Can it please be taken off hold now?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

Yesterday I asked a question on [parameterizations of knotted surfaces in $\mathbb R^4$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225145/parameterization-of-a-knotted-surface). After I stated in the comments that I wanted the question to be kept to the case of a general surface, the question was promptly put on hold as "unclear what you're asking". I then refined my question to make it clearer. A day has since passed, but the question has not been reopened. All there has been since then is one comment (after I altered the question) mentioning that the question does not seem unclear at all. I would very much appreciate it if the question could be reopened.

Comment: Your question has presently 4 pending votes to reopen.

Comment: @StefanKohl Ah. Can i see close/open votes on my own question?

Comment: You can see them once you have at least 250 points. (For other people's questions, the threshold is 3000 points).

Comment: @StefanKohl So, short of asking on meta like I've done here, is there any way I can be aware of the moderation status of my questions?

Comment: No, as long as you have less than 250 points, only other people can tell you. Also, if you would have 250 points, you could vote to reopen your own questions -- hence just cast the 5th vote now.

Comment: @StefanKohl So considering there are 4 pending votes to reopen, what remains to restore my question to open status?

Comment: I'm not familiar with these moderation issues.

Comment: Just a 5th vote (I have already voted, so can't cast another vote).

Comment: The question is open, now.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks. Should I delete this question on meta, since the issue has been resolved?

Comment: I don't know. ${}$

Comment: Or, for example, should I simply fix the title to say "... [resolved]"?

Answer (score 14):

Although the question at MO has been reopened, the meta post is not completely moot: let me remind users that there is a meta thread dedicated to the requests for reopening: [Requests for reopen and undelete votes for on-hold, closed, and deleted questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/223/requests-for-reopen-votes).