# Undelete request, Question 290941

Tags: discussion, undelete-request

Could I request that [Question 290941](https://mathoverflow.net/q/290941) be undeleted? It is a sensible question, and I spent some time finding a reference for the answer. It was then deleted by the poster - I have no idea why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Requests for reopen and undelete votes for on-hold, closed, and deleted questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/223/requests-for-reopen-and-undelete-votes-for-on-hold-closed-and-deleted-question)

Comment: You might want to post your question as an answer to https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/223/12357

Comment: For the benefit of users who are below 10k reputation points, at the moment some version of that question is still [visible in Google cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://mathoverflow.net/q/290941).

Comment: And it is also mentioned in the question that the same question was asked on Theoretical Computer Science site: [Is Normal centralizer problem in P?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/39798)

Answer (score 4):

The question has now been undeleted ([revisions](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/290941/revisions)/[timeline](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/290941/timeline)).