# I want to answer a closed question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation, re-open

Please reopen this question:
[A problem of an infinite number of balls and an urn](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7063/a-problem-of-an-infinite-number-of-balls-and-an-urn)

I have a nice answer.

(**Added (DR):** now re-opened. Please note there are ten deleted nonsense answers, which I imagine contributed to why the question was closed.)

Comment: I see that in your post you [linked to an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7063/a-problem-of-an-infinite-number-of-balls-and-an-urn/7113#7113). My guess would be that you probably wanted to [link to the question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7063/a-problem-of-an-infinite-number-of-balls-and-an-urn). (As a side note, I think that ([meta-tag:specific-question]) would be a reasonable tag here.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks

Comment: BTW the question has already got some reopen votes. Some of them [from the reopen review](https://mathoverflow.net/review/reopen/137383).

Comment: Can you give us a very brief description of how your answer differs from the existing ones?

Comment: @DavidRoberts I will give a precise answer to a simplified version of the problem and describe how the answer to the original version should differ.

Comment: @DavidRoberts And, by the way, it was closed as a narrow-usable but in fact it deals with the broad problem and paradoxes of supertasks.

Comment: @Anixx mostly it was closed because a troll was repeatedly posting nonsense as "answers" despite it being downvoted and deleted again and again.

Comment: I just cast the last vote to reopen.

Comment: There's a specific thread for such requests: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/223/requests-for-reopen-and-undelete-votes-for-on-hold-closed-and-deleted-question

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I'm not sure it was worth reopening the question for an answer that has quickly gotten a net score of -2, and whose content is...not quite of the same rigour as the other ten answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Requests for reopen and undelete votes for on-hold, closed, and deleted questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/223/requests-for-reopen-and-undelete-votes-for-on-hold-closed-and-deleted-question)

Comment: I just discovered I could protect questions, so I did so for this one, to avoid more drive-by shenanigans. If this is not needed I'm happy to remove, or have it removed.